# Define generic typescript sort function of a certain type

Tags: typescript

I have a bunch of objects that all have a property with the type of `Moment` but different names for the key.

I'm trying to write a small utility function using typescript where I can sort any of these objects.  Could use some shoving in the right direction.

```
interface ExampleType1 {
    startDate: Moment;
    // ... other members
}

interface ExampleType2 {
    dueDate: Moment;
    // ... other members
}

interface ExampleType3 {
    createdAt: Moment;
}
```

I would expect my function look something like this (half pseudocode):

```
function sortByDateAsc(data: ATypeThatHasAMoment[], keyName: KeyToTheMomentTypeWithinATypeThatHasAMoment) {
    return data.sort((a, b) => {
        // whatever sort logic i use here
        // accessing the Moment object via a[keyName] and b[keyName]
    }
}
```

I've been fiddling with something like this

```
function sortByDateAsc<T, K extends keyof T>(data: T[], dateKey: K);
```

Though within the function T[K] doesn't have a type?  I'm not sure how to tell the function "T[K] has to be of type Moment"

Answer (score 4):

You could do it this way:

```
declare function sortByDateAsc<K extends keyof any, T extends Record<K, Moment>>(
  data: T[], 
  dateKey: K
): T[];
```

where you are constraining `T` to be a type where `T[K]` is `Moment`.  This has the benefit of being simple to define and it works... but it might not give nice IntelliSense hints though. For example:

```
declare const ex1arr: ExampleType1[];
sortByDateAsc(ex1arr, "startdate"); // error
//            ~~~~~~ <-- "startdate" not in ExampleType1
```

This is given as an error on `ex1arr`, not an error on `"startdate"`.  Moreover it does not suggest `"startDate"` as a correction.

---

Instead you can use a more complicated [conditional type](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/What's-new-in-TypeScript#conditional-types) like this:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T];
declare function sortByDateAsc<T extends any, K extends KeysMatching<T, Moment>>(
  data: T[], 
  dateKey: K
): T[];
```

Instead of constraining `T`, that signature constrains `K` to be the keys where `T[K]` matches `Moment`.  Now the same example gives you a better error:

```
declare const ex1arr: ExampleType1[];
sortByDateAsc(ex1arr, "startdate"); // error
//                    ~~~~~~~~~~~ <-- does not match "startDate"
```

with better IntelliSense hints when you start typing the `dateKey` parameter (it suggests `"startDate"`).

---

Either way should work.  Hope that helps.  Good luck!