# In TypeScript, how to get the keys of an object type whose values are of a given type?

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics, mapped-types, keyof

I've been trying to create a type that consists of the keys of type `T` whose values are strings. In pseudocode it would be `keyof T where T[P] is a string`.

The only way I can think of doing this is in two steps:

```
// a mapped type that filters out properties that aren't strings via a conditional type
type StringValueKeys<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string ? T[P] : never };

// all keys of the above type
type Key<T> = keyof StringValueKeys<T>;
```

However the TS compiler is saying that `Key<T>` is simply equal to `keyof T`, even though I've filtered out the keys whose values aren't strings by setting them to `never` using a conditional type.

So it is still allowing this, for example:

```
interface Thing {
    id: string;
    price: number;
    other: { stuff: boolean };
}

const key: Key<Thing> = 'other';
```

when the only allowed value of `key` should really be `"id"`, not `"id" | "price" | "other"`, as the other two keys' values are not strings.

[Link to a code sample in the TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=type%20StringValueKeys%3CT%3E%20%3D%20%7B%20%5BP%20in%20keyof%20T%5D%3A%20T%5BP%5D%20extends%20string%20%3F%20T%5BP%5D%20%3A%20never%20%7D%3B%0D%0Atype%20Key%3CT%3E%20%3D%20keyof%20StringValueKeys%3CT%3E%3B%0D%0A%0D%0Ainterface%20Thing%20%7B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20id%3A%20string%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20price%3A%20number%3B%0D%0A%20%20%20%20other%3A%20%7B%20stuff%3A%20boolean%20%7D%3B%0D%0A%7D%0D%0A%0D%0Aconst%20key%3A%20Key%3CThing%3E%20%3D%20'other'%3B%0D%0A)

Comment: *Possibly* duplicating [Define generic typescript sort function of a certain type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51573206/define-generic-typescript-sort-function-of-a-certain-type) or at least my answer is kind of the same

Comment: If using a library is allowed, `ts-toolbelt` has [`Object.SelectKeys`](https://millsp.github.io/ts-toolbelt/modules/object_selectkeys.html#selectkeys) that could be useful.

Answer (score 124, accepted):

There is a feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992) to support this natively.  Until and unless that's implemented though, you an make your own version in a number of ways.

One way is with [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) and [indexed access types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html), like this:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T];
```

and then you pull out the keys whose properties match `string` like this:

```
const key: KeysMatching<Thing, string> = 'other'; // ERROR!
// '"other"' is not assignable to type '"id"'
```

In detail:

```
KeysMatching<Thing, string> ➡

{[K in keyof Thing]-?: Thing[K] extends string ? K : never}[keyof Thing] ➡

{ 
  id: string extends string ? 'id' : never; 
  price: number extends string ? 'number' : never;
  other: { stuff: boolean } extends string ? 'other' : never;
}['id'|'price'|'other'] ➡

{ id: 'id', price: never, other: never }['id' | 'price' | 'other'] ➡

'id' | never | never ➡

'id'
```

---

Note that what you were doing:

```
type SetNonStringToNever<T> = { [P in keyof T]: T[P] extends string ? T[P] : never };
```

was really just turning non-string property *values* into `never` property values. It wasn't touching the keys.  Your `Thing` would become `{id: string, price: never, other: never}`.  And the keys of that are the same as the keys of `Thing`.  The main difference with that and `KeysMatching` is that you should be selecting keys, not values (so `P` and not `T[P]`).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcCyBDYBjAFgSwHYHMAeAFQBooA1APigF4oBvAbRijygGt4B7AMymIBdALQB+AFwCWgqBAAewCLgAmCSlFGwok3BABuEAE4BfJlxB8BggNwAoe3kWHeKdNGI4CjW1F9tlkgjAhnj4dn5QYCFuOgCuALYARkbhftzAmEaSDFBBsby8konc3AA2ECi4UMZ2xvbo3LhBnPCScIioGJ5EHqHkQSEENPQA5OmZhiPWUAD0M1AAogBKSwDySwCEtnNQIwBE40Z7I2xquOlQKAgI2Pi4KInlUMDcz+DQ+9jKx7ZAA)

Comment: This does seem to work! Could you briefly explain why this works and my attempt doesn't?

Comment: Ok that makes sense, though not sure I'd ever have come up with that myself. Thanks @jcalz!

Comment: This works perfectly! Could you explain how it works? Thanks!

Comment: What is that "-" before the "?" ?

Comment: It's a [mapping modifier](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#mapping-modifiers) that removes optionality from all props

Comment: At the end of the type definition you have `[keyof T]`. Is this to access each key of the created type and it returns just "id", since only "id" is not `never`.
Is my thinking correct?

Comment: Yes, it returns the union of the properties, which is `"id" | never | never` which collapses to `"id"`

Comment: For use-cases where you want to match *any* of the possible values of a property, such as finding all the nullable properties - swapping the 'extends' around is useful, eg: `V extends T[K]`, which can then be used as `KeysMatching<Thing, null>`

Answer (score 39):

As a supplementary answer:

Since version 4.1 you can leverage [key remapping](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html#key-remapping-via-as) for an alternative solution (note that core logic does not differ from jcalz's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520829/11407695)). Simply filter out keys that, when used to index the source type, do not produce a type assignable to the target type and extract the union of remaining keys with `keyof`:

```ts
type KeysWithValsOfType<T,V> = keyof { [ P in keyof T as T[P] extends V ? P : never ] : P };

interface Thing {
    id: string;
    price: number;
    test: number;
    other: { stuff: boolean };
}

type keys1 = KeysWithValsOfType<Thing, string>; //id -> ok
type keys2 = KeysWithValsOfType<Thing, number>; //price|test -> ok
```

[Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHNkG8CwAUMicsACYBcyAzmFNgNxGnIAODS1IArgLYAjaM2KlIdbvyFQRrAPZh00arlpgeMGNQFy5AGwhwQyAL4iTRImACebFAGkI1mgHVgigGpw9NAPIxUWwgAHlQAGg8APmQAXmQAayc5GDxkAG1kAAUyY0TrZLRkOBo0NMyAXWQIAA9IEHISj2QAfizkbggAN2hkSupss0tCGzsEpxoARljkR2c3T28-AKDQzBAsMLUGdcjGZAB6fYpkAFpouXirILHnACZp2dd3dC8ff0C7VexN3kFoXYO%20w4wCQAB9xGBTud4kA)

---

As rightfully mentioned by [Michal Minich](https://stackoverflow.com/users/56165/michal-minich):

> Both can extract the union of string keys. Yet, when they should be used in more complex situation - like T extends Keys...<T, X> then TS is not able to "understand" your solution well.

Because the type above does not index with `keyof T` and instead uses `keyof` of the mapped type, the compiler cannot infer that `T` is indexable by the output union. To ensure the compiler about that, one can intersect the latter with `keyof T`:

```ts
type KeysWithValsOfType<T,V> = keyof { [ P in keyof T as T[P] extends V ? P : never ] : P } & keyof T;

function getNumValueC<T, K extends KeysWithValsOfType<T, number>>(thing: T, key: K) {
    return thing[key]; //OK
}
```

[Updated Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.2.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgCoAtQHNkG8CwAUMicsACYBcyAzmFNgNxGnIAODS1IArgLYAjaM2KlIdbvyFQRrAPZh00arlpgeMGNQFy5AGwhwQyAL4iTRIgjkg6yRdmSUMjgLx4yVAEQBGLwBp2TghqAGYAOh8AFkDxMGofACZQwIUlKBU1DS17KB4UEzNLQiIwAE82FABpCDKaAFk4MARMECwAHlRAgDUAPmR3VQBtKrJjAGtauRg0AF0AWgB%20alQR2eQIAA9IEHIaZG7kReRR7ggAN2hTIcmy6bmRcsqT2poAdWBFbrg9GgB5GCoCoQTr%20PoDZC3e7DZAABTGkKmM1QyDg%201WsPWWx2ewORzhTmQIAuV3W1HhRRKhCeKFuNAAghCanVGs1Wh0XG1ArxBNBeo9gYi6gAhJmvD5fH7-QHAzrs7lSPkiUqCuKM9ycrA3V702YC55xUUa9nakV64owHggBBgYA2ZBYCBgABy-G%20eny9NBJw22wgu32zIaTRa2G9POkvV6AAoHG0VoFbtQqgBKPAsUhQJ08KDGONa27mwgWKmW622%202Ol1un75YXe0bY-24oMS9Du6VAyrhxVQKOx9kJoXJtMEUQkAD0E4AAmAaPMtpUbQuoFA5DIMyQs%20pc-YTYXGMgp7dkAgjAByMDIITIHg0CDkexyMbkLZoIgllXPVufdtSgFdhAzLTKC4LuFCMwwvCoBCvcKJomgQyYr6OL7IcxzwmclxQMgZIEiYyAAGSwciyqEGWNp2sYVaunw7r5AAwg2KHNoG4q-h2AHAsBMA9ryfYxvmQ5Jico6bsg245nm%2061HqR4Tn8VQfsUNIvHUbacTKlQAKLbFAiBgKB-TuLp9AGe0EEeEMBIwZZ8HokhWJ%20gGeIYYSxLYbhhIUomSJoPyFpWpRlZOrR9EQAAIsxTYuT%20kq-FxOl6eZXREr2-ZCWgvllCO6bjhJ2a7vmppyVOikfkAA)

Comment: Although this answer and answer from jcalz generate same type, the one from jcalz is better because Typescripts remembers that the resulting keys come original object T and can be used later to index it as in T[K]. with this answer, the TS 4.3 does not know that and issues error "Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'T'.ts(2536)"

Comment: In TS 4.3? I thought we barely have 4.2.3 (probably just a typo) Re: indexing - am I missing something here (https://tsplay.dev/m3Aabw), could you add a link to a playground to take a look at?

Comment: Please look at https://tsplay.dev/mxozbN It shows usage of both solutions (from jcalz and yours). Both can extract the union of string keys. Yet, when they should be used in more complex situation - like `T extends Keys...<T, X>` then TS is not able to "understand" your solution well. Maybe it is bug worth reporting. I noticed the jcalz solution is even better in nightly, where it understands what the type of property of computed keys used on and object is.

Comment: @MichalMinich - thanks, I thought you'd never get back to that :) Will take a closer look today, but it seems that indexing with `keyof T` does let the compiler know that the resulting type is `keyof T` while in my version, due to using `keyof` of the mapped type, the compiler does not know that. Does not look like a bug, I understand the logic behind that. I see two ways out of it. The first is to intersect with `keyof T` to assure the compiler. The second - `Extract<[our type], keyof T>`. Both work, I will amend the answer

Comment: ^ but the latter is obviously more verbose to little to no benefit, so I'd stick with `keyof T` intersection - it is much more elegant. But that's probably one too many `keyof`s :)

Comment: @OlegValteriswithUkraine is there a way to let the compiler know that in this case,  `thing[key]` is of type number?

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone else had the same questions as myself, I was trying to use a pattern like this for indexing into a a generic object property with type inference in React, but couldn't get it to work.

```
function ListWithSum<T>({
    data,
    value,
}: {
    data: T
    value: KeysMatching<T, number>
}) {
    // 'item[value]' would not have type 'number', causing a type mismatch
    const sum = data.reduce((total, item) => total + item[value], 0)
    // ...
}
```

By introducing an extra type `PickKeysInMatching`:

```
type PickKeysMatching<T, V> = {
    [key in KeysMatching<T, V>]: V
}
```

And using it to constrain `T`, I can safely index into the `value` prop, correctly resolving to type `number`.

```
function ListWithSum<T extends PickKeysMatching<T, number>>({
    data,
    value,
}: {
    data: T
    value: KeysMatching<T, number>
}) {
    // 'item[value]' is now a 'number'
    const sum = data.reduce((total, item) => total + item[value], 0)

    return (
        <ul>
            {data.map((item) => (
                <li>{item[value]}</li>
            ))}
            <li><b>Sum: {sum}</b></li>
        </ul>
    )
}
```

When using the component, type is also checked on keys passed to the props. As the prop `value` expects a key to `number` property, passing `value='title'` will cause an error as `Contract.title` has type `string`.

```
type Contract = { title: string; payment: number}

function Example(){
    const contracts: Contract[] = [
        { title: 'Walking neighbourhood dogs', payment: 300 },
        { title: 'Built website for client', payment: 2000 },
        { title: 'Mowed parents lawn', payment: 50 },
    ]

    return <ListWithSum data={contracts} value='payment' />
}
```