# Filter generic type properties to specific type

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to find a way to tell the TypeScript's compiler that a value is (take a deep breath) a key of a generic type that, if applied to an object of that type, will result in a property of a specific type. I'm aware this sentence is really confusing, so here's a concrete example.

```js
const obj: T = an object of type T;
const key: KeysMatching<T, U> = a key that matches `typeof T[key] === U`;
const attribute = obj[key];
```

Here, I expect `attribute` to be of type `U` or to be assignable to type `U`.

I got inspired by the [*Filter* helper](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#example-1) provided in TypeScript's documentation, tried using the type proposed in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520676/in-typescript-how-to-specify-only-keys-of-a-generic-object-whose-values-are-stri#answer-54520829) that seemed to be a good fit for my case (but isn't apparently), and finally tried to create my own a helper that filters properties of some type:

```js
type KeysMatching<T, U> = T[keyof T] extends U ? keyof T : never;
```

Currently, with my custom solution, the type of `attribute` is `T[T[keyof T] extends U ? keyof T : never]` and it is not assignable to `U`.

Is there a way to achieve what I want to do ?

I tried to give a minimal reproducible case, but if you need more information, context or real case examples, feel free to ask !

Thank you in advance to any one who may be able to give me some ideas or solutions.

Comment: Is this generic type in the context of a function or a class ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use generic types parameters in conditional type typescript can't do much reasoning about them as long as there are still unresolved type parameter in them. This is why from the outside of the generic class/function things will work as expected but inside, where the generic type is still unknown the compiler will not let you do much with such types:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];

function test<T, K extends KeysMatching<T, string>>(o: T, k: K): T[K] {
    let v = o[k];

    v.toLowerCase() // error 
    return v;
}
test({ a: ""}, "a").toLowerCase() // ok from outside
```

You can sometimes get around this by constraining `T` instead of `K`.

```
function test<T extends Record<K, string>, K extends PropertyKey>(o: T, k: K): T[K] {
    let v = o[k];
    v.toLowerCase(); //ok
    return v
}
```

This does have limitations, from example intelisense does not display suggestions for `K`.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification ! I don't think a can use your workaround in my case, as I need my type to allow other properties. I'll probably stick to the awful `as unknown as U` for this time.

Comment: @EnzoBaldisserri the option above will allow extra properties, it will just constrain the one specified by `K` to be `string`

Comment: Oh ok, I didn't realise that. I'll work out how to make it fit in then. Thanks a lot !