# Why won't TS let me index into a compatible object type?

Tags: typescript

I have the following type definitions.

```
type Key<Row> = {
  [P in keyof Row]: Row[P] extends string ? P : never
}[keyof Row];

type ID<Row> = Row[Key<Row>];

type Selected<Row> = {
  selected: boolean;
} & Row;
```

`Key<Row>` returns all the property keys of `Row` whose values are strings. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520829/3229534) for how it is constructed.

`ID<Row>` is a union of all the string values of `Row`. It is always a `string` but narrows nicely if the string value is a string constant, e.g. in

```
interface X {
  prop: "abc";
}
```

`ID<X>` is always `"abc"`.

`Selected<Row>` is an intersection type of whatever `Row` is plus the property `selected: boolean`.

With all the above defined, I don't understand why the below function definition throws an error:

```
const getId = <Row>(row: Selected<Row>, key: Key<Row>): ID<Selected<Row>> =>
  row[key];
```

The type error TS gives me is pasted below, but I can't work out why TS doesn't like my code.

From what I can see `row[key]` should always work because even if `row` is `Selected<Row>`, `Key<Row>` only contains a narrower set of keys, so what's the problem with keying into an object that has more properties than the key we're actually using?

[Here is a link to the TS playground with this code showing the error](https://typescript-play.js.org/#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIB4BKB7A7gPigXigbwCgooBtABSgEsA7KAa3hQDMpU0BdALlfXPaggAPYBGoATAM5QJwAE40A5lAD8UCt2oQAbhFkEAviQYhmPDgG4CBUJCgBJACLJ0WXGxJxEbDO0vXw0ADKEAA2EADGImLOmDj4RNKhEVHcAEYoKGEAhtSW+lAAZGZ+4SjUMlAKEMB2YnExGAAUsujcwWGRENHeADT08NyeDQCU3I4I7cldDa4YCS1oRvC+VgD0AFTrROtQACoQFWiUwAAWULIQWSFQNhDbq1Y0IrJMWeHQuyeK8cRilBJZVJhMRpDLZXIJSgg6RyRSWYgoU66QKw6gKbgAIkB4QxeSstz2XzRnjiQ0+igwfgJ5LRk06YhJuCGdKiCBpCgwlP8tnZjji43ZXIIVRq0UFjQSeCgfwBQK63FeIQkED6UMxXwxfURJ2RqPRUCxqRxfWVHRSN1kAFdoPoegkMVCMQRhpYgA)

---

```
Type 'Selected<Row>[{ [P in keyof Row]: Row[P] extends string ? P : never; }[keyof Row]]' is not assignable to type '{ selected: boolean; }[(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)] & Row[(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<...>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)]'.
  Type 'Selected<Row>[Row[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never]' is not assignable to type '{ selected: boolean; }[(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)] & Row[(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<...>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)]'.
    Type 'Selected<Row>[keyof Row]' is not assignable to type '{ selected: boolean; }[(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)] & Row[(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<...>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)]'.
      Type 'Row[string] | Row[number] | Row[symbol]' is not assignable to type '{ selected: boolean; }[(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)] & Row[(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<...>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)]'.
        Type 'Row[string]' is not assignable to type '{ selected: boolean; }[(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)] & Row[(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<...>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)]'.
          Type 'Row[string]' is not assignable to type '{ selected: boolean; }[(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)]'.
            Type 'Row' is not assignable to type '{ selected: boolean; }'.
              Type 'Row[string]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
                Type 'Selected<Row>[keyof Row]' is not assignable to type '{ selected: boolean; }[(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)]'.
                  Type 'keyof Row' is not assignable to type '(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)'.
                    Type 'keyof Row' is not assignable to type 'Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never'.
                      Type 'Selected<Row>[keyof Row]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
                        Type 'Selected<Row>[Row[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never]' is not assignable to type '{ selected: boolean; }[(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)]'.
                          Type 'Row[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never' is not assignable to type '(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)'.
                            Type 'Row[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never' is not assignable to type 'Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never'.
                              Type 'Selected<Row>[Row[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
                                Type 'Selected<Row>[{ [P in keyof Row]: Row[P] extends string ? P : never; }[keyof Row]]' is not assignable to type '{ selected: boolean; }[(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)]'.
                                  Type 'Row[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never' is not assignable to type '(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)'.
                                    Type 'keyof Row' is not assignable to type '(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)'.
                                      Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type '(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)'.
                                        Type 'string' is not assignable to type '(Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never) & (Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never)'.
                                          Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never'.
                                            Type 'keyof Row' is not assignable to type 'Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never'.
                                              Type 'string | number | symbol' is not assignable to type 'Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never'.
                                                Type 'string' is not assignable to type 'Selected<Row>[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never'.
                                                  Type 'Row[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never' is not assignable to type 'Selected<Row>["selected"] extends string ? "selected" : never'.
                                                    Type 'Selected<Row>[{ [P in keyof Row]: Row[P] extends string ? P : never; }[keyof Row]]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
                                                      Type 'Selected<Row>[Row[keyof Row] extends string ? keyof Row : never]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
                                                        Type 'Selected<Row>[keyof Row]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
                                                          Type 'Row[string] | Row[number] | Row[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
                                                            Type 'Row[string]' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

Answer (score 2):

The compiler isn't as clever as you are, especially when it comes to reasoning about conditional types that depend on unresolved generic parameters (like `NonSelected<Row>[P] extends string ? P : never`).  If you've gone over the logic and are sure that what you're doing is safe, a judicious [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/basic-types.html#type-assertions) is warranted:

```
const getId = <Row>(row: Selected<Row>, key: Key<Row>) =>
  row[key] as unknown as ID<Selected<Row>>;
```

Or, you can give the compiler something it *can* reason about, such as that an object of type `O` indexed by a key of type `K` will produce a value of type `O[K]`:

```
const getId = <Row>(row: Selected<Row>, key: Key<Selected<Row>>): ID<Selected<Row>> =>
  row[key];
```

Either of those should appease the compiler and your examples continue to behave as expected.

Hope that helps.  Good luck!

Comment: Ok makes sense. Thank you.
Btw you also answered my initial question about how to construct the `Key<T>` type in the first place :)