# Defining a type for object properties that are strings. Differences between generic and explicit types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics, mapped-types, conditional-types

[Playground link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAaRhAzgWQIZgMYAsCWAdgOYA8AKgDRwBqAfHALxwDeA2gnEXANbID2AMzjkAugC4RHUXBgAPMDEIATFLTgB%20RHEmEYANxgAnAL5s%20EISNEBuUKEiw4AVRTGmrOIPxGUYAHIYALYwkn5GRMTUADYYfoEhYWARJNQYxKFwhACuQQBGxiag0TBgcNluvpKuxmwyzGygcM2e3r4BwZkA5ABS-LiEXTFxHYlwXQDKQfhguENw6ZkATEsmlE0tLF4%208Z2SXeQwyvOxu2O9-YQo-INpGZIAzKugoqCC2YTYYPg3cG4YRjwhwUAElCDVfAAKCrGFDVSp1ajhSIAMXwMGiqkkSFQmBwBBIpAhSOSkToiLgigUSRSxAAlPDaqIWBtmkZStkjIRypUUAA6bzRRRGaGVJh0VktZrIkhojGqPnXEKQ7zy8U82qqzGiPlgfgAGX4AHdjABhOIwSF0vlEbDRbLKGAoSFUsC6g3Gs0Wq10umSul2EBFEDvT7fX7-QG4YFgCh0SEYmAhQhgOFSUQk2lyzFpnHoLB4SIUTNkimummRBnplkgKXssCc7mJ5OpgX4IXGBMlFvqyVSmXEbMKpWWrXKdXNpRgNhjnV6w0mozmtxWm2fe2O52u90Lr0r31%202stAOgYOgbA3a4lPnRfjESGRoHyMBgiHOmG%20ahsLptM4weZdKcoz-hm4wAFaXF0vrnpe-DXre96PtGz6irCX4-jswEAUBCQgdQXQQQMUF0kAA)

I want to define a function `searchText` that takes an array of objects that needs to be filtered, array of object properties that will be searched through and a string value that will be searched for. In the end I want something like this to be possible:

```
type User = { firstName: string, lastName: string, age: number}
let users: User[] = [
    { firstName: 'John', lastName: 'Smith', age: 22},
    { firstName: 'Ted', lastName: 'Johnson', age: 32}
]
searchText(users, ['firstName', 'lastName'], 'john') // should find both entries
```

I want to constrain this function to only accept valid arrays of property names. A valid array should only contain properties that have a type of string since the function is searching for text. In another SO question I found a way to define type that should only allow valid values (https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520829/1242967). This type is defined as

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T];
```

With this type I am able to define a function that allows specifying the 'valid array constraint'

```
function searchTextInUsers(users: User[], stringFields: KeysMatching<User, string>[], text: string): User[]{
    return users.filter(user =>
        stringFields.some(field => user[field].toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()))
    );
}
```

This compiles and works as expected. Trying to pass a non-string property causes a compilation error

```
searchTextInUsers(users, ['firstName', 'lastName', 'age'], 'john') // ERROR: Type 'string' is not assignable to type '"firstName" | "lastName"'.
```

But what I actually wanted to do is to write a function that would work for any type, not just `User` but surprisingly just adding a generic type parameter did not work.

```
function searchText<T>(elements: T[], stringFields: KeysMatching<T, string>[], text: string): T[]{
    return elements.filter(element => 
        stringFields.some(field => element[field].toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase())) // Error on this line
    );
}
```

Compiler shows the following error

> Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'T[{ [K in keyof T]:
>   T[K] extends string ? K : never; }[keyof T]]'

Could someone explain why this did not work and why typescript does not narrow the type down to a string in this case? Is there another way to achieve what I want to do when using generic types? [Playground link here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAaRhAzgWQIZgMYAsCWAdgOYA8AKgDRwBqAfHALxwDeA2gnEXANbID2AMzjkAugC4RHUXBgAPMDEIATFLTgB%20RHEmEYANxgAnAL5s%20EISNEBuUKEiw4AVRTGmrOIPxGUYAHIYALYwkn5GRMTUADYYfoEhYWARJNQYxKFwhACuQQBGxiag0TBgcNluvpKuxmwyzGygcM2e3r4BwZkA5ABS-LiEXTFxHYlwXQDKQfhguENw6ZkATEsmlE0tLF4%208Z2SXeQwyvOxu2O9-YQo-INpGZIAzKugoqCC2YTYYPg3cG4YRjwhwUAElCDVfAAKCrGFDVSp1ajhSIAMXwMGiqkkSFQmBwBBIpAhSOSkToiLgigUSRSxAAlPDaqIWBtmkZStkjIRypUUAA6bzRRRGaGVJh0VktZrIkhojGqPnXEKQ7zy8U82qqzGiPlgfgAGX4AHdjABhOIwSF0vlEbDRbLKGAoSFUsC6g3Gs0Wq10umSul2EBFEDvT7fX7-QG4YFgCh0SEYmAhQhgOFSUQk2lyzFpnHoLB4SIUTNkimummRBnplkgKXssCc7mJ5OpgX4IXGBMlFvqyVSmXEbMKpWWrXKdXNpRgNhjnV6w0mozmtxWm2fe2O52u90Lr0r31%202stAOgYOgbA3a4lPnRfjESGRoHyMBgiHOmG%20ahsLptM4weZdKcoz-hm4wAFaXF0vrnpe-DXre96PtGz6irCX4-jswEAUBCQgdQXQQQMUF0kAA)

Answer (score 0):

Put simply, typescript isn't as smart as you want it to be in this case.

In your `searchTextInUsers` function, it knows that `type K = KeysMatching<User, string>` can only be `"firstName" | "lastName"` and sees that both of these keys return `string` properties from `User`.  But it's not able to figure that out from the `KeysMatching` type alone.

Instead of working backwards, use a generic that allows typescript to move forwards.

```
function searchText<K extends keyof any, T extends Record<K, string>>(elements: T[], stringFields: K[], text: string): T[]{
    return elements.filter(element => 
        stringFields.some(field => element[field].toLowerCase().includes(text.toLowerCase()))
    );
}
```

Here we say the type `K` represents the string property keys that we are passing in as `stringFields`.  Our elements must have all of these keys, and we know that the corresponding values are `strings`, so we say that `T` must extend `Record<K, string>`.

This works as expected. `searchText(users, ['firstName', 'lastName'], 'john')` is fine.  But if we try to pass in a property name that is not a string property, like `'age'`, we'll get an error because the data array `users` doesn't fulfill the contract `{age: string}`.

`searchText(users, ['firstName', 'age'], 'john'))` gives this error:

```
Argument of type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; age: number; }[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<"firstName" | "age", string>[]'.
  Type '{ firstName: string; lastName: string; age: number; }' is not assignable to type 'Record<"firstName" | "age", string>'.
    Types of property 'age' are incompatible.
      Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

[TS Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/LAKALgngDgpgBAaRhAzgWQIZgMYAsCWAdgOYA8AKgDRwBqAfHALxwDeA2gnEXANbID2AMzjkAugC4RHUXBgAPMDEIATFLTgB%20RHEmEYANxgAnAL5s%20EISNEBuUKEiw4AZTBGixZwFcARihhgFAzMAEow2PxGyqRIqJg4BCQU1ChuHnQpaSR09uDQ8ACq-kZMrHCC%20EapAHIYALYwkqnuJNQANhg19Y1wzR7UGMQ9hF51PsYmoG0BcF7FasxsoHArZRVVYLUNkgDkAFL8uIQ77Z2b3bvOdfhguCdwgz0ATE8mlMurLOWVXdtwO%20QYMp7h1fj19odCCh%20McBkNJABmV6gUS5RzwTjMWLoLB4DykIrGTItYh0OwgUCCLyEbBgfAw3owDBGPCAhQASUIhKqAAo5sYUJJuWxRMSPAAxfAwNqqSTY%20J4pLcsXZEXURQKJpZYgASiFxRFLA%20KyMAS8RkIs3mADoKm1FEY%20cUmDkQKt3b1tZLpaprdCGjyKj6XVbjGwgzLRNawPwADL8ADuxgAwp0YDyddaiNg2l5lDAUDyNWBo3HEym0xmdTrjXAdeTJhSQFSaXSGf5maz5IFON2lKpeAJhBhCBBqORZAp%202owhEojEVaS6DzpTAGoQwIKpKLPSTvTKtwg1XBi1qSXrt0a3atTWBzZbV%20vN7b8PbjCvpk%20Q7X3X0SPvfX9dMI2UENHyUMBwylSNS3jJMjFTfwMyzGlc3zQti1g8sEMrasa2vFZ61ARsHHyOAAEFSnlXFEjIdErH5Ko2AABh3P9SVIpwACFSlcElvD8AJSHo4RGJQFjRFdUAIihfhpmtNp%20GIHkOxZXA2TATluULMTqDYHZ1jBe4dlBc4Gh2HcdgAK0hHZq2kmFoXkxTlNUrsFCdAU9IMn4zJgYzTK2fzLJso47PwmSnJgBSlJUpk1I0zyqm8wy-OMx4LOoazbOrIA)