# Restricting by type of value on index types in TypeScript generics

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I have a class:

```js
class AdderEffect<T, K extends keyof T> {
  key: K;
  value: T[K] & number;

  constructor(key: K, value: T[K] & number) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = addend;
  }

  apply(state: T): T {
    // do arithmetic things and return a copy
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      [this.key]: this.value + state[this.key]
    });
  }
}
```

The idea is that `T` is a generic object, `K` is a key on that object. However, as part of the `apply` method, I'd like to be able to perform an arithmetic operation on that key. So, I need to restrict K in such a way that it's associated value *type* is number.

A usage might look like:

```js
interface Point = {
  x: number;
  y: number;
};

const obj: Point = { x: 1, y: 2 };
const adder = new AdderEffect<Point, 'x'>('x', 3);

adder.apply(obj); // returns { x: 4, y: 2 }
```

whereas

```js
interface Animal = {
  name: string
}

const adder = new AdderEffect<Animal, 'name'>({ name: 'Fido' }, 1);
```

should fail.

This really feels clunky (especially that `<Point, 'x'>('x', 3)` business...) so I'm curious if there's a nice way to restrict `K` such that `T[K] extends number`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to make a constraint on `K` that enforces that `T[K] extends number` for a given `T`: I usually call this `KeysMatching` and you'd write `K extends KeysMatching<T, number>`.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520676/in-typescript-how-to-specify-only-keys-of-a-generic-object-whose-values-are-stri) for an implementation.

I'm not including that as the answer here, though, because I don't think it really helps you much.  Partly because the compiler will not understand that `T[KeysMatching<T, number>]` will be compatible with `number` (it would require a higher-order sort of generic type reasoning than currently supported), and you'd end up needing a lot of type assertions to move forward.  But more than that: your `AdderEffect` doesn't take a value of type `T` until you call the `apply()` method, leading me to believe that `AdderEffect` should only be generic in `K` and not `T`.

---

So, my inclination would be to turn your constraint around... let `K` be any property key, and have `T` be constrained to something with a `number` at `T[K]`.  This is easier to express: `T extends Record<K, number>` and easier for the compiler to reason about.

And since an instance of `AdderEffect` doesn't really care about `T` until you call `apply()`, I'd move the `T` generic off of `AdderEffect` and onto the `apply()` method.  Something like this:

```
class AdderEffect<K extends PropertyKey> {
  key: K;
  value: number;

  constructor(key: K, value: number) {
    this.key = key;
    this.value = value;
  }

  apply<T extends Record<K, number>>(state: T): Omit<T, K> & { [P in K]: number } {
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      [this.key]: this.value + state[this.key]
    });
  }

}
```

I also decided to make `apply()`'s return value not be of type `T`, but of type `Omit<T, K> & Record<K, number>`.  This is a subtle difference but could be important if you ever pass in a type `T` where `T[K]` is *narrower* than `number`, such as a [numeric literal type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/advanced-types.html#numeric-literal-types) or union of numeric literals.

---

Let's see how it works.  First, we don't have to specify any generics when we create an `AdderEffect`:

```
const adder = new AdderEffect('x', 3);
// const adder: AdderEffect<"x">
```

The `K` type is inferred to be `"x"` above.  Now, your `Point` should work:

```
interface Point {
  x: number;
  y: number;
};
const obj: Point = { x: 1, y: 2 };
const newPoint: Point = adder.apply(obj); // okay
```

And something else where the `x` property exists but is not a number, will not:

```
interface SomethingElse {
  x: string;
  y: number;
}
const els: SomethingElse = { x: "one", y: 2 };
adder.apply(els); // error! 
// -------> ~~~ 
// string is not assignable to number
```

Finally, let's see what happens in the case where the `x` property is narrower than `number`:

```
interface BinaryPoint {
  x: 0 | 1;
  y: 0 | 1;
}
const bin: Point = { x: 1, y: 1 };

const somethingNew = adder.apply(bin);
// const somethingNew: Pick<Point, "y"> & { x: number; }
// equivalent to const somethingNew: { x: number, y: 0 | 1 }

const newBinaryPoint: BinaryPoint = adder.apply(bin); // error!
// -> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// number is not assignable to 0 | 1
```

You *can* apply the `adder` to a `BinaryPoint`, but what comes out is no longer a `BinaryPoint` but a value of a type like `{ x: number, y: 0 | 1 }`.  So it will let you call it but it won't let you assign the result to a `BinaryPoint`.

---

Okay, hope this helps; good luck!

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/MYGwhgzhAECCAm8CmAnAogMw04AXAPANLRIAeuSAdvDAAooD2ADqrgJ6FJsB80A3gFgAUNGgBrLgC5ohANzDRANzAgArkmmVVAWwBGqeUIXRgDShFwpVeBigAUEttMIAaaMrUboWvagCU-MaiuAAWAJYQAHSO0AC84lyGosHhUR7qce4q6knQAL7CxmBMTCBs+AAqJORUNNAASji28ERuPvoo3Nx2FmAU0hV+0gDy2mEEFW6EvABk-NAA2rTQYZQyALqaOh35gSLJKEi4qihrw7oAVji4kZAQYQDmlHZ8eW69FG6C+8mLoRHRLibaD-NLZJDQADU0A+SAWoMBbHWQXyflyBSMQgxCkKQlM5lw0DAiFQmUoSAA7nASegsNc7AByUgMtwAZjRwgA9JyTGYLESadIEMhadg8PgAESkCXcXGrCgoDBgYAQ2gMeV7USkLa+FC5JzebYGYR5Qz4-kMS7SNUa+J8aDa6AARjcBoATPkzXzCeSKTbKLhreqA5liSLbiUynZLRc0dBudAGGIwGxccJ5aglSroABlBjaI7hSgPNAgCAQ75a6QWFCrB76nUdQwY82EpBl6R5gv-Yul8uZe2OiVmJAS13SD2m4Rh1AR0psOztiBxhOoRgoACE0C5PIAtPuD7veAA-U-boQJmt1lYwSgMQl3R6UMC6EAQ3AMQ26uUBzPKiEAEKrGAKBsP6hKVg60gAAzQAAPs6DbQLBCFOs2wittAuirEGtrzI6LrQAaTqehh3owvmhZ1gAcpSoY0nOUbYZQHIXjymEQJRPYPLRFLWmEwBiPg4FuBKbAytAcyDo2Bj5DuJAAI6qGEHhUISH68gSFHdkWPGUtI0lfh047IfBzpyZimG+kBz6geB0g2SBYHBoS8QzigjELsxK48mutgbvJR7QKeIWhWF8ntKSETePeRJQE+L5viCn4oc6whAA)

Comment: Wow, super helpful! Thank you very much! This worked perfectly.

After posting I realized an omission that changed some implementation. Here's my _real_ class definition:

`class AdderEffect<K extends PropertyKey, T extends Record<K, number>> implements Effect<T> `

So, I ended up needing the T anyways for the `Effect<T>.