# Typescript: Narrowing down mapped types does not work with generics

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

The Problem: I want to write a function that takes an object and the name of a property as parameters. What I want
to achieve is that only property names of properties with a specific type are accepted.

Example: In a person
object I have fields name:string and age:number, my function should then only be able to be called with the parameters
(person, 'name'). This can be achieved by creating this type:

```
export type OnlyPropertiesWithSpecificType<TYPE, T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends TYPE ? K : never;
}[keyof T];
```

When accessing the property inside the function the type of the property's values should be constrainted like this:

```
type Person = {
  name: string;
  age: number;
};

function somePersonFunction(obj: Person, param: OnlyPropertiesWithSpecificType<string, Person>): string {
  return obj[param]; // works, obj[param] is of type 'string'
}
```

However when I try to generify the function, it is no longer type constrainted:

```
function someGenericFunction<T>(obj: T, param: OnlyPropertiesWithSpecificType<string, T>): string {
  return obj[param]; // doesn't work: "TS2322: Type 'T[{ [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never; }[keyof T]]' is not assignable to type 'string'."
}
```

This is confusing, because the compiler still only accepts property names belonging to properties of type 'string' as param:

```
someGenericFunction(person, 'name'); // works
someGenericFunction(person, 'age'); // doesn't work
```

What I tried:

- TS versions 3.4.5 and 4.1.2.
- Various variations on T, i.e. T extends object

I created a sandbox with the above example: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-ypy0b

How do I solve this problem?

Comment: Does this answer help? https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520829/3229534

Comment: @Aron thanks! Unfortunately no... I replaced OnlyPropertiesWithSpecificType with your KeysMatching and still - in the generic example it doesn't get the correct type out of it

Comment: Does my answer help?

Answer (score 2):

It looks like TS hasn't worked out that `someGenericFunction` will always return a `string`, even though in practice it always will.

However unless you absolutely need the `: string` return type annotation from `someGenericFunction`, you can just omit it and your code will work as expected.

```
function someGenericFunction<T>(
  obj: T,
  param: OnlyPropertiesWithSpecificType<string, T>
) {
  return obj[param]; // inferred return type is T[OnlyPropertiesWithSpecificType<string, T>]
}
```

When called with actual types TS does infer that `T[OnlyPropertiesWithSpecificType<string, T>]` will always be assignable to `string`, which is why the functions do work.

Comment: Thanks again! This does indeed work for all following usages of someGenericFunction. It would also work with T[OnlyPropertiesWithSpecificType<string, T>] as explicit return type.
The problem is, I need the string inside someGenericFunction. When useing const val = obj[param] inside of someGenericFunction, its type is not string and I don't understand why. Is this a bug?

Comment: Can you give me more context on why you need its type to explicitly be a string?

Comment: It doesnt have to be the return type but i want to call a function whos param type is string, like this: https://codesandbox.io/s/typescript-forked-yn9mx

Comment: @MoritzHohmeier that seems to work just fine. The compiler lets you call `doSomethingWithAString(obj[param])` without any errors. Is there still a problem?