# How can I tell Typescript to check that object[key] is of certain type?

Tags: typescript, types, typescript-generics

Let's assume that I have a Typescript function like this:

```js
const myFunction = <U, V extends keyof U> (object: U, key: V) => {
    // ...
}
```

How can I tell Typescript to check that `object[key]` is of certain type?

For example, let's say that I want `object[key]` be of type 'string'.

So, when I call `myFunction` it should work like this:

```js
myFunction({keyA: "hello", keyB: 123}, "keyA") // OK

myFunction({keyA: "hello", keyB: 123}, "keyB") // error: `keyB` must be of type string but is number
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the answer at [In TypeScript, how to get the keys of an object type whose values are of a given type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520676/in-typescript-how-to-get-the-keys-of-an-object-type-whose-values-are-of-a-given) I put together this worked example answering your question specifically ( [see playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=9&ssc=101&pln=1&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcCyBDYBjAFgSwHYHMAeAFQBoA1APigF4oBreAewDMoBvKAbSgAUo8DZm2JQUCKMS68AulAgAPYBFwATCeSgB%20PlABcUXBABuEAE5Q5B-gF8A3ACgHLAK650wbE1xQAtiAAxNw8vXBJKAAomACMAKwgPAzIhEAM4RFQMHAISUgRgMzx8agBKdgcoSqgAemqoADpGhxsnfyD3T28I9kYQAEEDACJMCAAbUaZB0hSAIQMARgAmAGYbacHevsGSmrqAeRhWwODO3G7NoZHxyeneuagl1fW77d35MzMmMwMAAzufvwufJQaLQVhQUCQKD5QoEEEuYACCS4Fy%20UFmIA) ) but the hard part is really from the other answer.

```
type KeysMatching<T,V> = keyof { [ P in keyof T as T[P] extends V ? P : never ] : P };

function myFunction<T>(object: T, key: KeysMatching<T,string> ){
    // ...
}

myFunction({keyA: "hello", keyB: 123}, "keyA") // OK

myFunction({keyA: "hello", keyB: 123}, "keyB") // error: `keyB` must be of type string but is number
```

---

I quite like the form of extracting a `PickValues<T,V>` type which filters the properties of T to only those with values in V. Then simply use `keyof` on that...

```
type PickValues<T,V> = { [ P in keyof T as T[P] extends V ? P : never ] : T[P] }
type Picked = PickValues<{keyA: "hello", keyB: 123},string>;
// type Picked = {
//     keyA: "hello";
// }

//Your case
function myFunction<T>(object: T, key: keyof PickValues<T,string> ){
    // ...
}
myFunction({keyA: "hello", keyB: 123}, "keyA") // OK
myFunction({keyA: "hello", keyB: 123}, "keyB") // error: `keyB` must be of type string but is number
```

Incidentally, this strategy can then be generalised to do the opposite and create an `OmitValues<T,V>` type...

```
type OmitValues<T,V> = { [ P in keyof T as T[P] extends V ? never : P ] : T[P] }
type Omitted = OmitValues<{keyA: "hello", keyB: 123},string>;
// type Omitted = {
//     keyB: 123;
// }
```

Finally, it can also be repurposed to extract only properties which are of an Optional nature...

```
type OptionalValues<T> = { [ P in keyof T as undefined extends T[P] ? P : never ] : T[P] }
type Optional = OptionalValues<{keyA?: "hello", keyB: 123}>;
// type Optional = {
//     keyA?: "hello" | undefined;
// }
```

Comment: This was a really inspiring and challenging question (though it looks disarmingly easy). It taught me new stuff about Typescript. From there, I've been trying to perfect the answer above. I found constructing utility types PickValues and OmitValues to be a good way to reason about the problem and define the key unions. I also discovered I could extract OptionalValues. The playground is at https://tsplay.dev/m3AV2w

Comment: It doesn't really change the answer, but writing it in a different way helped me follow the solution a bit better.