# Generic method with related arguments

Tags: typescript

Assume

```ts
abstract class CustomisationProvider {
  abstract fetch(id: string): any;
}
```

I want to add type definitions the `fetchThings` function

```js
function fetchThings(sources, ids, services){
  for(const s in sources){
    services[s].fetch(ids[s]);
  }
}
```

One valid type annotation that is accepted by the typescript compiler is

```ts
function fetchThings<
  IDs extends { [key: string]: any }
>(
    sources: string[],
    ids: IDs,
    services: {
      [key: string]: CustomisationProvider
    }
  ){
  for(const s in sources){
    services[s].fetch(ids[s]);
  }
}
```

However, this does not capture the fact that the elements in `sources` are expected to be key of `services` and keys of `ids` and that `ids[source[i]]` is string.

Starting from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520829/12750353) I would expect the following to work

```ts
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T];

function fetchThings<
  P extends KeysMatching<IDs, string>, 
  IDs extends { [key: string]: any }
>(
    sources: P[],
    ids: IDs,
    services: {
      [key: P]: CustomisationProvider
    }
  ){
  for(const s in sources){
    services[s].fetch(ids[s]);
  }
}
```

However, the TS compiler 4.3.5 will reject this with the message `An index signature parameter type must be either 'string' or 'number'.`

```ts
function fetchThings<
  P extends keyof IDs, 
  IDs extends { [key: string]: any }
>(
    sources: P[],
    ids: IDs,
    services: {
      [key: P]: CustomisationProvider
    }
  ){
  for(const s in sources){
    services[s].fetch(ids[s]);
  }
}
```

It will fail, what is very intriguing, since if `P` is key of `IDs` why it could not be a key of `services`. I have read that we cannot mix keys of different types.

i.e.

```ts
interface Y {
    [key: string ]: any,
    [key: number ]: any
}
```

is valid

but

```ts
interface X {
    [key: string | number ]: any
}
```

is not.

I tried to explicitly use type `P & string`, or `Filter<P, string>` where `type Filter<T, U> = T extends U ? T : never;` without success.

How could this type of relation to be represented in the type signatures?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```js
abstract class CustomisationProvider {
  abstract fetch(id: string): any;
}

type KeysMatching<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];

function fetchThings<
  P extends KeysMatching<IDs, string>,
  IDs extends { [key: string]: any }
>(
  sources: P[],
  ids: IDs,
  services: Record<P, CustomisationProvider>
) {
  for (const s in sources) {
    services[s as P].fetch(ids[s]);
  }
```

TypeScript does not preserve specific index types in a loop.

It might be obvious that `s` has `P` type, but TS infers it to `string`.
Same behavior for `Object.keys()`, it always infers to `string[]`.

```js
 for(const s /* s is a stirng */ in sources){
    services[s].fetch(ids[s]);
  }
```

Hence, in order to make it work, the easiest way is to make `type assertion`: `as P`

Answer (score 1):

Going to suggest a slightly alternative solution.

It seemed like your typesafety really hinges on your `Ids` or `Services` so I simply made `Ids` the origin of the derivative types.

This allows `s` to be used as a `string` in `sources` since the keys in `IDS` are inherently `strings`.

This also allows you to have typesafety when providing arguments to `fetchThings`.

```
function fetchThings<
    KEYS extends keyof IDS,
    IDS extends { [key: string]: any },
    SERVICES extends Record<keyof IDS, CustomisationProvider>
>(
    sources: KEYS[],
    ids: IDS,
    services: SERVICES
) {
    for (const s in sources) {
        services[s].fetch(ids[s]);
    }
}

// works
fetchThings(['two'], {
    'one': 1,
    'two': 'two',
}, {
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
})

// throws an error
fetchThings(['two', 'three'], { // "three" is not assignable to "two" | "one"
    'one': 1,
    'two': 'two',
}, {
    'one': 1,
    'two': 2,
})

// throws an error
fetchThings(['two'], {
    'one': 1,
    'two': 'two',
}, {
    'one': 1, // missing key 'two' in object
})
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I accepted the earliest. Your type exactly the expansion of `Record<keyof IDs, CustomisationProvider>`.