# Create a reverse type look up using the infer keyword?

Tags: typescript

Here's what I have, I have various types, and I have a string representation for that type:

```js
type PossibleValueTypes = Color | number | Position;
type PossibleValueTypesAsString = "color" | "number" | "position";

type ValueTypeMap = {
  "color" : Color; 
  "number" : number; 
  "position" : Position; 
};
```

Now, give a given string representation, returning the the value type is easy enough, for example;

```js
function generateRandomValueOfType<T extends PossibleValueTypesAsString>(type: T) : ValueTypeMap[T] {
    if (type === 'color') {
        return {
            r: 1, 
            g: 1, 
            b: 1, 
            a: 1, 
        } as ValueTypeMap[T]
    }
    if (type === "position") {
        return {
            x:1, 
            y: 1
        } as ValueTypeMap[T]
    }

    if (type === "number") {
        return 1 as ValueTypeMap[T]; 
    }

    throw new Error ("We shouldn't have got here"); 
}; 


const a: Position = generateRandomValueOfType("position"); 
const b: number = generateRandomValueOfType("position"); // Expected error!
```

Now the question is - what if I want to do the opposite, that is - given a value type, determine the string representation.

The best I've got is to do a chained conditional like:

```js
type ReverseValueTypeLookup<T extends PossibleValueTypes>  = T extends Color ? "color" : T extends number ? "number" : T extends Position ? "position": never; 

function hasAValueAcceptingCallback<T extends PossibleValueTypes> (callback: (value: T) => void, valueTypeAsString: ReverseValueTypeLookup<T>)  {
    const value = generateRandomValueOfType(valueTypeAsString); 

  //Argument of type 'ValueTypeMap[ReverseValueTypeLookup<T>]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'T'.
  //'ValueTypeMap[ReverseValueTypeLookup<T>]' is assignable to the constraint of type 'T', but 'T' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'PossibleValueTypes'.
    callback(value);
}
```

But this doesn't actually work in the example I've given.

Is there a tidier way to achieve both of the thing I'm trying to do here?

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=58&ssc=2&pln=59&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAwg9gGzgJygXigbwFBT1ZALigDsBXAWwCMJkBuKXfAc2POtuKbyrcpqKN8UAIZ8O9RgF9s2UJCgAFOAGcAlsDVwS6LNygAPcQIb6Qx2qZlzw0ZSvVUEEAGoiEZCABVbK3fCRUAB9SflooEPsNLRI6GwV7R2c3D29fAEEVAGVgZDUSZl0AIgBjRBQiiKgi9gFKkKKwVWjtIrjZeWgUzx9IAFkRMF0cPFLy5EriAJRTUdraSdCJWeqm9U1WqGIojdjpU1kAMzISEt2oZggSWhFgCAAlERIAEzgKbogAeUPeiAAeLxQCAGO4vPyJNROVzuHoZbK5fLMAB8AApOsQvABKLZQD6-AZgADaXgAunphGpDlA0bZ0GgMAByMqBBnYkbCfDICDAMjIHTsjkcwQARgANEJBRzWFAxRLJfheDLxfp5WIlXKOVJRH48bYCcSSfoZBSqTSFPSMI1mrsimyVZzubz%20fbBUZZS6OeYZR6tSIdTC0v1BgajbITdTOnTLfMJnb5VyeXyZdrcQH8cHSSs8NZhMAABbIOAAd1IEBLAFFkIXUCiigB1aAqPNwMgIZ4kBnAKB5kQAN2gzDgXbztAgtqsB2wZRIKi7ap2MV0l2uyFuDyer3eAe%20v1raxaJHHjGns6gipjS6uNzujxebw%20O9se%20tMSPAHo31BywZIGcIM8gSrFAAEJZA6Wl7ggftkBUaFUl%20AAZOA4AAazIMAASBEErmecFVCSODYUgFQkTwDBAWBUFcNgcYoAAfmqZkKhxCjsLBJYBHo6oY0WViqLw9ZFwYq1BNaNgoMsRhsGOU5zh7FR0g%20dIShKCAwE0AoYHcBAqBEEoUMwyicIEgjdWI0iURKbTdP04gUV7AMMWxNBSN7OA1GecUHPg2xMhyPICmISDoNgsyICQ1D0IBJFsXJfATy7bzPEvFc11vTcHx%20J8ksDCA-IRApMSzKArIQHS9JQ%20yAyK7BrGwIA)

Comment: If I translate the [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520829/2887218) to the other question here I get [this](https://tsplay.dev/wXkyLW), but note that in both this and your accepted answer you can't call `callback(value)` without a type assertion; the compiler just isn't clever enough to see that this will be safe.  But your question as asked seems to be "make a reverse type look up" and not "convince the compiler that `Fwd<Rev<T>>` is equivalent to `T` when `T` is some unspecified generic", so I'm not going to worry about that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A quite verbose but working solution is...

```js
type ReverseValueTypeLookup<T extends ValueTypeMap[keyof ValueTypeMap]> = {
  [x in keyof ValueTypeMap]: ValueTypeMap[x] extends T ? x : never;
}[keyof ValueTypeMap];
// exclude key x when ValueTypeMap[x] is not assignable to T, and then get the types of values

type C = ReverseValueTypeLookup<Color>; // type 'color'
type N = ReverseValueTypeLookup<number>; // type 'number'
```

If you still can't distinguish the types among `Color | number | Position`, use type narrowing like...

```js
var data: Color | number | Position;
if (typeof data === 'number') {
  // data is number
} else if ('r' in data) {
  // data is Color
} else if ('x' in data) {
  // data is Position
}
```