# How can I have TypeScript guarantee that a generic type has a property that implements a specific method?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

The best way for me to ask this question is to give an example.

Let's say I want to implement a method which takes three parameters, like so:

```
customFilter<T>(values: T[], filterString: string, propName: string) any[] {
    return values.filter((value) => value[propName].includes(filterString));
}
```

In this case, I want to ensure that `T` is a type which has a property `propName` which evaluates to a `string` (or, at the very least, something which implements an `includes` method).

I've considered writing an interface to use as the first parameter type, but I feel that is just my C# background peeking through. Since the interface would require me to, essentially, hardcode the property name, I don't think that's the right approach.

I know it involves the use of `keyof`.

I have worked around the issue by doing a quick check in the method:

`typeof(values[propName].includes) === 'function'`

That, though, feels too "JavaScripty", and, again, I feel like there's probably something in TypeScript that can do this for me.

I know doing something along the lines of [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14426274/2526084) would also work, but that still feels very JavaScript.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the example code you provided, you want to filter the `values` argument against a `filterString` of which you apply to a specified `propName` that should exist in generic `T`, but requires the value to be an array.

So we can highlight a few points that we should achieve:

i) We will need to constrain `T` to have a property that extends an `Array`. This will be a slight issue because `ts` has no direct way of defining an interface with at least one property of a certain type. We will provide
a cheat though that will maintain an indirect constraint.

ii) So now we move to the args. Firstly, we want the `filterString` to extend the generic type of the array you are filtering. For instance, say you want to filter a `propName` whose value is an `Array<string>`, so then we should expect `filterString` argument to be of type `string` right.

iii) With `T` constrained we will then need to define the argument `propName` to be keys of `T` whose values are arrays. i.e. `string` types.

The implementation of your function definition should stay the same, however we may rearrange the arguments for the order of definitions sake. So let us get coding:

We will first define a type that can pick out the properties from `T` that are
of a specific type. please refer to [@jcalz](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520676/in-typescript-how-to-get-the-keys-of-an-object-type-whose-values-are-of-a-given#answer-54520829) solution to defining such an interface.

```
type Match<T, V> = { [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T];
```

So we define the function as described in the steps above

```
// we define these types that will filter keys whose values are arrays
type HasIncludes<T> = Match<T, { includes: (x: any) => boolean }>;
// and a type that will extract the generic type of the array value
type IncludeType<T, K extends keyof T> =  T[K] extends { includes: (value: infer U) => boolean } ? U : never;

// we then apply then apply them to the args
function customFilter<T, K extends HasIncludes<T>>(values: T[], propName: K, filterString: IncludeType<T, K>) {
    // so here we have to type cast to any as the first cheat because ts
    // is unable to infer the types of T[K] which should be of type array

    return values.filter((value) => (value[propName] as any)
      .includes(filterString))
}
```

With the definition done we define some tests

```
const a = [{ age: 4, surname: 'something' }];
const b = [{
    person: [{ name: 'hello' }, { name: 'world' }]
}];

// so in this case you get the indirect error discussed in that any key
// you refer will not meet the requirement of the argument constraint
const c = [{ foo: 3 }]

// note the generic is implicity inferred by its usage
const result = customFilter(b, 'person', { name: 'type' }); // works as expected
const result = customFilter(a, 'age', 2); // ts error because age is not array
```

Here is my [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAsghsAxgCwDwBUA0UBqA+KAXigG8oBtAaSgEsA7KAawhAHsAzKdAXQFoB+AFxcq3KBAAewCHQAmAZ1xR+UasLoQAbhABOUAL7lmbTjwDcAWABQ10JCgAJOPICSdRABsArrIjyMBMTwSGhYpLTu3r7ywgAUEsJwdCAAlEQEAEasrB4QSQZ4llZ20G6ePhDo4BAY2NSS0nKKxhxcgVAilGINMgrh9OXRcZpw3hDC9Oy6UACqaYSZ2bn5+sqzUOpaukXW7F7uwDSsDIhe8sCsALYAYjQe0jq1quJSvYpOrpEV-uh4eNaxEZjGIibjYMA6VhgABycEu41U2HYdweAGVgDp6ABzYRlKKVapPSh4NIkawdDo6CDALw6BhArx+AB0yPuuligNGjPmBE5Y3IEKhsPhYmcUCSqSZA3x8lirLRGOxKRS1n01msAHoNVAAO7QXzIjTiqDSc7WRDHc7G4jkMhwLEI8gAFjBUHktLocIRAHJ5Fdqchsd6DNwiha6FaMkQKGSrBSoJAdH66MJbVBPfDhN7kBAPB5WMH9NgyBmfTrWDoPLJC9xVaH1VZw1aqe77tHTucrrc2TpYhlsN7E8nvcX016syVCykzEA) so you can tinker in case you want to test specific cases.

Comment: That's excellent! It looks like I had most of the pieces, I just couldn't get them into the right place. I ended up starting to build the `Match` type you demonstrated (though much less elegantly), but couldn't figure out how to make sure I'd get the right return type. It didn't occur to me that I needed a *third* type. I'm going to play with it a little and get it into my project, well done and thank you!