# In Typescript, how do you specify the type of properties of a Generic type?

Tags: typescript

I am trying to achieve something like this:

```
interface Thing {
  id: string;
  price: number;
  test: number;
  other: { stuff: boolean };
}

type KeysWithValsOfType<T, V> = keyof {
  [P in keyof T as T[P] extends V ? P : never]: P;
};

const list = [
  {
    id: "1",
    price: 0,
    test: 2,
    other: { stuff: true },
  },
  {
    id: "12",
    price: 0,
    test: 2,
    other: { stuff: true },
  },
] as Array<Thing>;

function doSomeSortingThingWithStringProperties<T, K extends KeysWithValsOfType<T, string>>(
  list: T[],
  sortKey: K
) {
  list.sort((a, b) => (a[sortKey] < b[sortKey] ? 1 : -1));
}

doSomeSortingThingWithStringProperties(list, "id");      // <= ok
doSomeSortingThingWithStringProperties(list, "other");   // <= should be rejected by the compiler
console.log(list);
```

I get "Type 'K' cannot be used to index type 'T'.(2536)" for

```
a[sortKey]
```

I already checked :
[In TypeScript, how to get the keys of an object type whose values are of a given type?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520676/in-typescript-how-to-get-the-keys-of-an-object-type-whose-values-are-of-a-given#answer-54520829)
and
[How can I have TypeScript guarantee that a generic type has a property that implements a specific method?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69231417/how-can-i-have-typescript-guarantee-that-a-generic-type-has-a-property-that-impl)

Any suggestion to solve this in Typescript ?

Comment: You can constrain `T` to `Record<K, string>` as well as constraining `K`, like [this](https://tsplay.dev/m3PKkW).  See the answers to the linked questions for more information.