# Narrow object keys only to those that have string values

Tags: typescript

I'd like to narrow object's keys to only those with string value. Here's an example:

```
interface Person {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  address: Address;
}

type onlyKeysWithStingValues = ??? // only the key name should be allowed
```

Basically I'd like to narrow keyof Person to only those keys with string values. Is it possible?

Comment: Using the `KeysMatching` type function from [the answer to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520829/2887218) gives you [this code](https://tsplay.dev/Wzo91w).