# Property type check

Tags: typescript

I would like to define type that would allow only to use object keys that extends certain type:

```
interface Foo {
    a: number
    b: string;    
}

const c: TKey<Foo, number> = "a" // ok
const c: TKey<Foo, number> = "b" // nok
```

I created `TKey` as such:

```
type TKey<T extends object, V> = T[keyof T] extends V ? keyof T : never;
```

however it seems it always unwinds to `never` - what I'm doing wrong?

[playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgGIHt3IN4FgBQyRycAXMiAK4C2ARtAccreQM5hSgDmA3EwQF8CBMAE8ADigAqAaQiiAPFOQQAHpBAATVsnS0AVhARgANMgBqAPmQBeZFIDaAa3noY9gLor1ELTvPIAPzILqJu9s)

Thank you!

Comment: I usually call this type function `KeysMatching`, as shown [here](https://tsplay.dev/WK7L8W).  You need to iterate over each key type instead of using `keyof T`.  See [the answer to the other question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520829/2887218) for more information.