# Signature for a base class function that wraps derived class functions

Tags: typescript

I'm defining a `_wrap` method on a base class, that modifies methods on derived classes.

```
class Base {
  //this is the signature I'm working out
  _wrap(key: unknown) {
      const fn = this[key]
      //I want typeof fn to be "Function"
      //which is not callable
      fn()
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super()
        //I want _wrap1 to require "isAFunction1 | isAFunction2"
        super._wrap("isAFunction1")
    }

    isAFunction1() { }
    isAFunction2() { }
    notAFunction = "some value"
}
```

I'm struggling to write the type signature of this method such that it:

1. Prevents calling `_wrap` from derived classes with keys that don't correspond to functions on the derived class
2. Allows me to use `this[key]` inside `_wrap` as the appropriate type without casting

I can use `_wrap(key: keyof typeof this)` to achieve #1, but not #2.

I feel like [this related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520676/in-typescript-how-to-get-the-keys-of-an-object-type-whose-values-are-of-a-given) should work. I don't understand why, but it doesn't meet either requirement - see the [code playground here](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcCyBDYBjAFgSwHYHMAeAFQBooA1APigF4oBvAbRijygGt4B7AMymIBdALQB%20AFwCWgqBAAewCLgAmCSlFGwok3BABuEAE4BfJlxB8BggNwAoW%20gA2KBGoBCL6A1tQoAfQB3QxQwAEYACnNJOERUDBwCQlBIS2AcBHIAMQBXXHRgbG5cKgBKRh9fSvQihGAoXlw6KDTsBDN4QQrKqAB6HoBJWTlIfObwCEsG5u4oACNoACIcvIKihfJZ7LrsYAByNVxuYHId-eb0lnhkNCw8IhaMqGX8wuLBci7KvoCcLDYDo5QdAoRzOWaOCCfXwNcIlCrGWwIhzOVxQAAiRmwBmUQ0UKncnnK3WquFqhmy%20W4hlhRO6lQQ2Ug1LhdK%20AyGIzqgWCYWmHIgowWrQAgs9VrhQlAAD7-UW5F5FABM6zmWzYewBx3V%20yhbIel1iNwS93SWXl4qo7ygP2wf2U3AgCFwuzqAFsjVAyXddb4GUyAHTckIRIUIOUrV4LFmVJHdEVi14RMreVm%20T6xyrx82vRU0lOp9P2bqHYDhhWNegLBDcV3QPQg7IQBaIoA).

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T];

class Base {
  _wrap(key: KeysMatching<typeof this, Function>) {
      const fn = this[key]
      //I expect typeof fn to be "Function", but it's not, it's this[KeysMatching<this, Function>], 
      //which is not callable
      fn()
  }
}

class Derived extends Base {
    constructor() {
        super()
        //I expect _wrap1 to expect "isAFunction1 | isAFunction2", but it's not, it's
        //this[KeysMatching<this, Function>], which doesn't match string
        this._wrap("isAFunction1")
    }
    isAFunction1() { }
    isAFunction2() { }
    notAFunction = "some value"
}
```

Is there a way to write this signature to achieve both these goals?

(Note: This is probably not ideal *code* in the first place. I'm annotating an existing library and not making code changes.)

Comment: Please include your [mre] as plain text in the post itself; an external IDE link is a great supplement but it doesn’t take the place of having the relevant code accessible directly in SO.

Comment: @jcalz I wasn't sure, edited

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mq5gqm) meet your needs? I'm not sure why you are trying to call `super._wrap1("isAFunction")` instead of (say) `this._wrap("isAFunction1")`, since `super` isn't known to have those subclass keys, and since `"isAFunction"` is not a key of anything in your example.  And I'm a bit wary of you calling methods without binding them or caring about parameters.  Maybe you can't modify the code in your actual use case, but for example code it's best not to distract focus from the issue at hand (i.e., the call signature for `_wrap1`).

Comment: @jcalz Fixed the examples a bit, thanks. I agree this is not a good approach generally,  just trying to annotate what's already there before reworking. This approach looks good, thanks! If you'd like to add it as an answer, I'll mark it accepted.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with using `KeysMatching<T, V>` is that the compiler is not clever enough to see that `T[KeysMatching<T, V>]` will be assignable to `V`.  It's a type function involving [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters, which the compiler mostly just defers and sees as opaque. See [microsoft/TypeScript#30728](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728) for more information.

On the other hand, the compiler *is* smart enough to understand that `Record<K, V>[K]` (equivalently `{[P in K]: V}[K]`) is assignable to `V`... that's a generic [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), with no conditional types getting in the way.

So this means you could try to constrain `this` to `Record<K, () => void>` for generic keylike `K` corresponding to the type of `key`, instead of constraining the type `key` itself.

Note that I'm using the `() => void` [function type expression](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function-type-expressions) instead of [the `Function` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#function); the former is specifically a function that can be (relatively) safely called with zero arguments, while the latter is an untyped function call which doesn't guard against misuse of parameter types.  If `fn` is `(x: string) => x.toUpperCase()`, you really don't want to call `fn()`.  If you check against `Record`, you'll get no compiler warning and the issue will only be seen as a runtime error.    If you check against `() => void`, the compiler will complain that `(x: string) => string` is not assignable to `() => void`.

---

Anyway, that call signature might look like:

```
class Base {
  _wrap1<K extends PropertyKey>(this: this & Record<K, () => void>, key: K) {
    const fn = this[key].bind(this) // <-- bound
    fn()
  }
}
```

I'm using a [`this` parameter](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-parameters) to tell the compiler that you can only call `foo._wrap1()` on an object `foo` assignable to `this & Record<K, ()=>void>` (the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of: [the `this` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/classes.html#this-types) corresponding to the type of the current derived subclass; and `Record<K, ()=>void>`.

Oh, another aside.  Your example code just calls `fn()` without first [binding it](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) to `this`.  That could be a big problem for any method implementation that dereferences `this`. And unfortunately TypeScript won't catch these errors for you easily, see [microsoft/TypeScript#7968](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7968) for more information.  So I wrote `this[key].bind(this)` to avoid runtime errors.

---

Let's test it:

```
class Derived extends Base {
  constructor() {
    super()
    this._wrap1("isAFunction1") // okay
    this._wrap1("isAFunction2") // okay
    this._wrap1("notAFunction") // error!
    //~~ <-- types of property 'notAFunction' are incompatible.
  }
  isAFunction1() { console.log(this.notAFunction + " says hello") }
  isAFunction2() { console.log(this.notAFunction + " says goodbye") }
  notAFunction = "some value"
}

new Derived() 
// some value says hello
// some value says goodbye
//  this[key].bind is not a function
```

Looks good.  Inside `Derived` the compiler accepts `this._wrap1("isAFunction1")` and `this._wrap1("isAFunction2")`, but rejects `this._wrap1("notAFunction")` which would lead to a runtime error.   The location of the compiler warning message you get is not the best, since it interprets the problem as being with `this` and not with `"notAFunction"`.  Not sure how much that matters, but changing that isn't simple (my brief attempts kept bringing back your original answers).

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?noErrorTruncation=true#code/MYGwhgzhAEBCkFNoG8CwAoa0D6B3ATmAA4CMAPANLQIAeALggHYAmMACvgPZEL50CeFBPwB8ACjoALAJYQAXNCmzoAMmgAlBME75mlADTQxASmgBeEdABunacxGGA1sIUVTaTFmjbGEOtAAzRnNFGQgAbWd+AF0AOgAjaRYJMNMAejToMgBabOh4zgBXFgwvQMYTaFLoAF8MOvQMUEgYABFeaSsEZmp6JlY4RBRqnz98QuA6HUqPMohCnnwTaqwlCFi8QlIxACJZAEEAMWLJ6U5GEh30zM5HMH4V0NkNgmISXYPjxlPzgCYr6AZaC3e6PNYvLbvHaMTh0I4nOhnRgAoG8Lj4ACEjwyAD8cVlcop+DwYJwAtAiFxFgJoAByGFwr4-Ri06BgfBIJLaAC2RDAiPiIAQsWqDSwnwRSPe7m85wgnCFsRAnAA5ilngz4d9EedoABqaA7aAQe4wSQIEDKgFi6AS7VI34zWW+BXC5Vq8Gapk64IGo0m-gwFWcTjMeL8BDW6peyW6syG+XcpBWMAgQqR+oYDCMBC4aDtfCdbqVDBAxPJ1Pp42m6Dmy2cUuZcvWStIANBkNhiONp4RKJxRIsW0wBlswKxxhAA)

Comment: Incredible answer, thank you! This really clarified the dead ends I was hitting.