# Preserve Type Restriction between Generic Variables

Tags: typescript, generics, typescript-generics

Assume that we have some class that has an important generic variable `T` and another class we have two fields, one wrapped, and one not:

```js
class Wrapper<V> {
    constructor(public value: V) {
    }

    clone(): Wrapper<V> {
        return new Wrapper(this.value);
    }
}

class SomeClass {
    value1 = new Wrapper(1);
    value2 = 2;
}
```

Then, we want a method `wrapperValue` which, when given an object (`obj`) and a field name (`name`) returns the value of wrapper accessed by `obj[name].value`. It is important that the return type is correct. So far, this is what I have managed to come up with:

```js
type WrapperKeyOf<S> = keyof {
  [K in keyof S as S[K] extends Wrapper<any> ? K: never]: any
}

type WrapperValueTypeOf<W> = W extends Wrapper<infer V> ? V : never;

function wrapperValue<S, K extends WrapperKeyOf<S>>(
    obj: S,
    name: K,
): WrapperValueTypeOf<S[K]> {
    const wrapper: Wrapper<WrapperValueTypeOf<S[K]>> = obj[name];
    return wrapper.value;
}

wrapperValue(new SomeClass(), "value1");
```

The type `WrapperKeyOf` restricts `name` to only to be keys of `S` where `S[T]` is a `Wrapper`, and `WrapperValueTypeOf<S[T]>` gets the wrapper type.

The TypeScript compiler produces the following error:

```java
Type 'S[K]' is not assignable to type 'Wrapper<WrapperValueTypeOf<S[K]>>'.
  Type 'S[keyof { [K in keyof S as S[K] extends Wrapper<any> ? K : never]: any; }]' is not assignable to type 'Wrapper<WrapperValueTypeOf<S[K]>>'.
    Type 'S[string] | S[number] | S[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'Wrapper<WrapperValueTypeOf<S[K]>>'.
      Type 'S[string]' is not assignable to type 'Wrapper<WrapperValueTypeOf<S[K]>>'.
```

It seems that the fact that `K` had to be a key of `S` which accessed a `Wrapper` gets lost. Is there any way to preserve this information somehow?

Comment: So the whole `value2` thing is irrelevant?

Comment: Sort of. I included it to show, that there may be things on `S` which are not necessarily of type `Wrapper<any`.

Comment: I just can't quite get it working. It's weird, I feel like I'm missing something obvious. I'll be keen to see the answers!

Comment: It's really weird, everything seems to be correctly defined and used, maybe we are overlooking it somehow, Interesting question!

Comment: The compiler cannot follow the abstract generic type analysis you are performing here;  see [ms/TS#30728](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728) for a description of what's happening.  The supported way to use mapped types and indexed access types instead of conditional types.  Like [this](https://tsplay.dev/w1yD2w).  If that addresses your question I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz - Brilliant, I never thought to come at it from the other direction (the key) like that.

Comment: @Napoleon - [Here's](https://tsplay.dev/mb0DPw) a version of jcalz's playground showing the return type and what happens when you use a non-`Wrapper` key or a completely invalid key (both result in errors).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately the compiler is unable to perform the kind of abstract [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type analysis necessary to verify that `T[KeysMatching<T, V>]` is assignable to `V` for generic `T`, where `KeysMatching<T, V>` is the union of property keys of `T` whose property values are assignable to `V`, as described in  [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54520676/2887218).  The problem is that `KeysMatching<T, V>` can only be implemented with a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) (somewhere in there you'll have a check like `T[K] extends V ? K : never`), and the compiler essentially treats conditional types that depend on generic type parameters as *opaque*, and chooses to *defer* evalutation of them until the generic type parameters are specified with some specific type.  This is effectively a design limitation of TypeScript, and is documented at [microsoft/TypeScript#30728](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728) and [microsoft/TypeScript#31275](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/31275) (and probably others).

Since your `WrapperKeyOf<T>` is an implementation of `KeysMatching<T, Wrapper<any>>`, it means that the compiler cannot see that `T[WrapperKeyOf<T>]` will be assignable to `Wrapper<any>`.

However, the compiler *can* tell that when you [index](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) of the form `{[P in K]: V}` (or the equivalent use of [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)) with a key `K` that you'll get something assignable to `V`.

So if you rephrase your requirement in terms of constraining `obj` instead of constraining `name`, you'll be able to get the sort of type safety guarantees you're looking for:

```
function wrapperValue<V, K extends PropertyKey>(
    obj: Record<K, Wrapper<V>>,
    name: K,
): V {
    const wrapper = obj[name];
    return wrapper.value; // okay
}
```

Here we let `name` be of generic type `K` which can be any key-like type, and then we restrict `obj` to be something with a key `K` and whose value at that key is of type `Wrapper<V>` for generic type parameter `V`.  Now the compiler knows that `obj[name].value` is of type `V`, so the implementation is error-free.

And your calls to `wrapperValue()` are still safe (although when you make a mistake the error will now be on `obj` instead of `name`):

```
const result = wrapperValue(new SomeClass(), "value1"); // okay
console.log(result.toFixed(1)); // 1.0

wrapperValue(new SomeClass(), "value2"); // error!
// --------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'Wrapper<number>'

wrapperValue(new SomeClass(), "value3"); // error!
// --------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
//  Property 'value3' is missing in type 'SomeClass'
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.6.2#code/MYGwhgzhAEDqBOYAOSCm8A8A1AfNA3gFDQnTAD2AdhAC7wCuwN58AFEvQEYgCWw0ANzAh6qAFzQsASgLFSAX0JySoKqlZSJCZGky5ZpQ9Hioa9eJWiVUAdziIU6VjQAWPCADohI1FIDcytCKioSgkDAAyuQAtqgAwuBQBqTeogCM0AC8Vrb2Ok5p-oGpqABMWdClASEAZvSUTDxU0DYOuljCotgANNAA0tCoAB40qJQAJjAACvDkujQAnn2oCzisgeScAFYSAEqoFPDjGH292o56ODjdgZRgsRKnhJqSySpUtC1t6BWbWwDad1iAF0AoYTGYLF98vAvJ1UNUlBRqDRjKgIPQQDQMtlWjCOj5WNY7FFYglwhpegAiEppKlFAD0DMMAD0APyEIA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Those references we also extremely useful! I didn't think of restricting the object in that way. I'll mark this as the answer :)