# Restricting parameter to keys of type that return a value of a type or a function that does the same

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

From a high level, I'm trying to define a generic type taking two types:

- T - The type
- V - The type of a value returned when accessing T with a key of T

Such that it allows a union of:

- Any keys of type T which return the type V
- A function that takes an instance of type T and returns a value of type V

To that end, I've defined the following:

```
type KeysWithValueOfType<T, V> = {
    [K in keyof T]-?: Exclude<T[K], undefined | null> extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T]
```

Which is taken from here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520829/50776

Then, I define a selector type which is the union of the key and the functional accessor:

```
type Selector<T, V> = KeysWithValueOfType<T, V> | ((t: T) => V)
```

At this point, I want to when trying to create a generic function to resolve the accessor to a value given an instance of type T

```
function getValue<Data extends Aggregate, Result>(
    selector: Selector<Data, Result>,
    data: Data
): Result {
    // If a function, evaluate, otherwise, use as a key
    // into the object.
    return typeof selector === 'function' ? selector(data) : data[selector]
}
```

However, it gives me the following error:

```
Type 'Result | Data[KeysWithValueOfType<Data, Result>]' is not assignable to type 'Result'.
  'Result' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Result | Data[KeysWithValueOfType<Data, Result>]'.ts(2322)
```

If I try and decompose the ternary operator:

```
function getValue<Data extends Aggregate, Result>(
    selector: Selector<Data, Result>,
    data: Data
): Result {
    // If the accessor is a string, evaluate and return it.
    if (typeof selector === 'function')
        return selector(data)

    // Use the accessor
    return data[selector]
}
```

It looks like the line:

```
return data[selector]
```

I get a slightly different message:

```
Type 'Data[KeysWithValueOfType<Data, Result>]' is not assignable to type 'Result'.
  'Result' could be instantiated with an arbitrary type which could be unrelated to 'Data[KeysWithValueOfType<Data, Result>]'.ts(2322)
```

Is there a way to accomplish what I'm looking for?

I am currently using Typescript 4.6.3.

I've also created a code sandbox which shows the issue, the error is in `getValue` towards the end:

https://codesandbox.io/s/selector-example-0gbfhm?file=/src/index.ts

Comment: Can you share the typescript playground link of the working code snippet, we will be able to gauge the behavior in a better way.

Comment: @Bishwajitjha Updated with a link to a code sandbox which lays it out.

Answer (score 0):

You are not specifying the shape of `Data`. TypeScript does not know that `data` being indexed with any key will lead to a result of type `Result`.

It's hard to know if the following solution will work for your use case, but you can add a constraint to `Data` to `extends Record<string, Result>`:

```js
function getValue<Data extends Record<string, any>, Result>(
    selector: Selector<Data, Result>,
    data: Data
): Result {
    // If the accessor is a string, evaluate and return it.
    if (typeof selector === 'function')
        return selector(data)

    // Use the accessor
    return data[selector]
}
```

Maybe you can add some examples where you call the function to see if this fits all use cases?

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Unfortunately, if I do that, I get `Argument of type 'Data' is not assignable to parameter of type 'Record<keyof Data, XAxisId>'.
  Type 'Aggregate' is not assignable to type 'Record<keyof Data, XAxisId>'.ts(2345)`.  Note that I used `keyof Data` and not `string` for the key parameter of `Record<K, V>`.  Using `string` also gives me an error.

Comment: can you share the definition of `Aggregate`?

Comment: It's a simple construct, a flat object with scalar values (strings and numbers).  I'll have an example when I update the question with a TS playground or codesandbox.

Comment: I've added a link to the codesandbox in the question.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Using `Record<string,any>` your examples work fine

Comment: @casperOne I think Tobias edited solution should solve your problem.
Typescript was complaining you that `T`could be of any type there was no constraints on it, by making sure we added `Record<string, any>` we have added the constraint which then allows us `Index access` of T