# Understanding TS Conditional types

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

I'm trying to write generic variadic function but am falling at the first hurdle, here is a simplified example that fails and I can't understand why.

```
type TestType = {
    x: string,
    y: number,
}

type PickKeys<T extends object, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = T[K] extends string ? [K] : [never];

function testFn<T extends object>(...keys: PickKeys<T>) {}

testFn<TestType>("x"); // Argument of type 'string' is not assignable to parameter of type 'never'.
```

If I remove "y" from the TestType signature or change it to string it works but I thought this format would extract the keys where their value was of type string.  I am clearly missing something fundamental.  Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is the question here "how can I write `PickKeys`"?  Or is it "why doesn't my version work"?  If it's the former then we can point to [existing answer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54520676/2887218).  If it's the latter then one could go through and explain what the problem is, but then the working version would be out of scope.  Please advise.

Comment: Many thanks, I think that existing answer is enough information, the key in keyof syntax is likely what I need and makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that `T[K] extends string ? [K] : [never]` does not *distribute* over [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) members in `K`.  It is not equivalent to `(T["x"] extends string ? ["x"] : [never]) | (T["y"] extends string ? ["y"] : [never])`.

That sort of automatic splitting-and-joining of unions only happens with a [distributive conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html#distributive-conditional-types), where the type being checked is the type parameter over whose union members you want to distribute.  But `T[K]` is not a type parameter (`T` is a type parameter, and `K` is a type parameter, but `T[K]` is not... much like `t` might be a variable and `k` might be a variable but `t[k]` would not be) so `T[K] extends ... ? ... : ...` will not distribute over unions at all.  And in any case you want to distribute over unions in `K` and not `T[K]`.

So your `PickKeys` is therefore equivalent to

```
type PickKeys1<T extends object> = 
  T[keyof T] extends string ? [keyof T] : [never];
```

And if you plug in `TestType` you get

```
type PickKeysTestType = 
  TestType[keyof TestType] extends string ? [keyof TestType] : [never];
type PickKeysTestType1 = 
  (string | number) extends string ? ["x" | "y"] : [never];
type PickKeysTestType2 = 
  [never];
```

Since `string | number` is not a subtype of `string`, the conditional type evaluates to the false branch, which is just `never`.  Oops.

---

If you want to distribute over unions in `K`, you can wrap the whole thing in a "no-op" distributive conditional type:

```
type PickKeys2<T extends object, K extends keyof T = keyof T> = 
  K extends unknown ? T[K] extends string ? [K] : [never] : never;
```

And then things work as desired:

```
function testFn<T extends object>(...keys: PickKeys2<T>) { }
testFn<TestType>("x"); // okay
```

There are [other ways](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54520676/2887218) to implement something like `PickKeys` (I'm not sure why we need tuples here) but that's out of scope for the question as asked.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&module=1&ssl=9&ssc=43&pln=8&pc=1#code/C4TwDgpgBAKhDOwbmgXigbwFBSgDwC4pEAnASwDsBzAGhyhCIoFcBbAIwhLoF8stQkKAAUyAYwDWAaQgh4AHhhQIeYBAoATeFAD27AFYQxwGlCnLV6rVAmydAM1hR0tkA9gA+Z7ADaUgLoWaprapJRUUAD8UH6BRD4UEABuXP4A3AIoUADyOmDa6KKSMnKKCEgoHmlQAPQ1UILQufneCcmp-I0i4tKy8ACMikFW2nqGxl7oMD6u7jCBKsHWYdRRMbOO81DxiSkk6ZlCRb1ycIjIQlPlFxAzdpvXKAuWIcTA5KvRd24P50-bMV2qQyXWOJXgZwqkH63gAFCsIgAfKAsDhcACUw1eCLWPgARHg8VBkXiQHi4oD2vsQVkwX1ITcAEytIHU-h1Bg6ZhQVgAQxAUAAFryUlBOOoLJBjOFfAEsct3jKvnKdlTAsAdFANGQwuxmGozLo9lBmBQyDoKDyIGiSPA6By9cAoGQnTqUTonbytTrFY6yKKxBbtcBzRReQAbBooarAYVOi3hgXCsCQCjaADugolsegXTAvJIvNYEDUJCNXCgmfEgs5zCwHPTvIoTo13t1+ugbu1JCMwETUDEWckEA0pnDZFshsWIxNFAkFB06ct0Wmcun2MVn3W91gFLaewOh2gdLkjKG6+sY17pnMF+0GycLh3MEmU5e1lN88Xy9lzyWoU3CJlT3VkKVZDJ7FNaULQacoADEKHPd9RgMXsPFhAA6LDXHgIgT3gM8X0xDAoD4NREAQso-kgdCCTxdFqg5HQJH5IA)

Comment: Thanks that makes even more sense, much appreciated.