# Typescript create type from static values of class

Tags: typescript

I have a Market `class` which has only 1 parameter: name.

```
class Market {
  name: string

  constructor(name: string) {
    this.name = name
  }
}
```

I then have a Markets `class` which is a `static` collection of several markets.

```
class Markets {
  static M1 = new Market("M1M")
  static M2 = new Market("M2M")
  static M3 = new Market("M3M")
}
```

I was wondering if there was a way to extract all name parameters from all markets into a type, such that the type would look something like this:

```
type MarketNames = "M1M" | "M2M" | "M3M"
```

I know about the `keyof` operator, is it the way?

Thanks.

Comment: [TS keys of type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520676/in-typescript-how-to-get-the-keys-of-an-object-type-whose-values-are-of-a-given).

Comment: @caTS I have read it, but don't know how to apply it in order to get the value.

Comment: @caTS In the answer you've attached he is trying to get the keys whilst I'm trying to get the values.

Comment: Ah... I did not read that closely. I assumed you got the result from the key names...

Comment: @Riccardo You're not just trying to get the values, you're trying to get the parameters used to instantiate the static values. That's much more difficult, and doesn't line up with the title of the question. (I'd call it impossible _unless_ you change the definition of Market to be generic based on the string literal passed in, and at that point I think it makes sense to define the constants elsewhere and programmatically create the static members.)

Comment: @JeffBowman You reckon I'm just better off manually listing the type through string union?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For this to work, your class has to be generic, so we can "extract" the generic out of it later:

```
class Market<Name extends string> {
  name: Name;

  constructor(name: Name) {
    this.name = name
  }
}
```

Then we create our type to extract the names:

```
type NamesOfMarkets<T> = Extract<T[keyof T], Market<string>> extends Market<infer N> ? N : never;
```

We're filtering out the values of the class for only Markets, then we infer the name and return that.

Note: you must pass the class as `typeof Markets` to get the constructor type. `Markets` by itself is simply a class instance.

[Playground](https://tsplay.dev/wXj39m)

Comment: Thanks! Just checked your GitHub. Where did you learn types so well? Do you have any resource to suggest?

Comment: You pick up a few things when using a language for some time. I didn't really use any resources, but I found a really good one that is unfortunately a work-in-progress: https://type-level-typescript.com/. Also check out [Typescript Deep Dive](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/).

Comment: Last clarification, what is the purpose of typeof Markets? To gain access to the static methods?

Comment: Yes, basically.