# How to constrain type to be a key in a generic object who's value is a string

Tags: typescript

I have an interface called `MyInterface` that looks like this:

```
interface MyInterface<T, K extends keyof T> {
  key: K
  data: Array<T>
}
```

I want to constrain the `key` prop to be only keys that are present in T and also where the keys in T are only strings. The above interface constrains the key, but not its value to only strings. How can I add this constraint? Some examples of the behavior I'm looking for:

```
interface Data {
  foo: string
  bar: number
}

const d: Data[] = [{ foo: 'xxx', bar: 1 }]

// this is valid as the key is in the Data interface and the value of the key is a string
const a: MyInterface<Data, 'foo'> = { key: 'foo', data: d }

// this should be a type error as the value of bar is a number, not a string
const b: MyInterface<Data, 'bar'> = { key: 'bar', data: d } 

// this should also be a type error as the key is not in the object
const c: MyInterface<Data, 'baz'> = { key: 'baz', data: d }
```

Comment: Both `obj1` and `obj2` have `Data[]` type,this is why you dont have an errors

Comment: Look at the last example `const d`. It has the `Data[]` type and has the correct error because the key `baz` is not in obj2.

Comment: @jcalz: thank you. that is precisely what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would like to ensure that in `MyInterface<T, K>`, the `T` type has a `string` property at key `K`.  There are a few ways to write this.  For example, you could constrain `K` to `KeysMatching<T, string>` where `KeysMatching` is described in the answer to [In TypeScript, how to get the keys of an object type whose values are of a given type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54520676/2887218).

But it's even more straightforward to constrain `T` to `Record<K, string>` (using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype)):

```
interface MyInterface<T extends Record<K, string>, K extends keyof T> {
    key: K
    data: Array<T>
}
```

Then your examples work as desired:

```
const a: MyInterface<Data, 'foo'> = { key: 'foo', data: d }; // okay
const b: MyInterface<Data, 'bar'> = { key: 'bar', data: d }; // error!
// ----------------> ~~~~
// Type 'Data' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<"bar", string>'.
// Types of property 'bar' are incompatible.
const c: MyInterface<Data, 'baz'> = { key: 'baz', data: d }; // error!
// ----------------> ~~~~
// Type 'Data' does not satisfy the constraint 'Record<"baz", string>'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ts=4.9.3#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgLIE8CS5ryQHgBVkIAPSEAEwGdkAlCBAeykvwGkAaZasKUAOYA+buxLkIVWgGsI6JjGSEhyAN4AoAJCz0ALmTstlOGDj6AglChx0RIeoC+69aEixEKACIm4arTCYmfV5+EAEtACM4KH0QAFcAWwjoR2dmEF5kSn1vUwBtAF1kAF5kPNVkAKDkAHJSepruKJjkAEZkBwK0pgywZDM0LBx3Aly4bhqqmpVSip19ScDGrJ99Sg6AbmQAem3kJmkbdXTMiP0MbDc8CHwxiebpkrVkedqH7mNTNc2dvegoFgAQnUu2QAFoIZCodCwSoAH4IuEgvaEdAABxQNTGNSyTAgtBATD61BMwGoMHQyDAAAsUCc+HBXLUGMxWPgAETNdncEKCIQ1AB0yKU6Px+0UaIBGKgYEpNQe-SgKFAzASaNJEQANhAhfTkAhzkMrh5bj57nAAF6PWYvOQLKJWj6rLI-UH-IHCmFeyHwxHC1EY2rY3FiwnE0nkyk0uk9EKM8DMxgsNicy3cnh8PmC5zqIA)