# typescript - making sure that value of obj[key] which are passed to function is specific type

Tags: javascript, typescript

I'm wondering if you could help me,
I'd like to have a simple function to sort array of objects case-insensitive, example of usage:

```
myArray.sort((a, b) => sortArr(a, b, 'someKey'))
```

Function itself is dead simple:

```
const sortArr = (
  firstItem,
  secondItem,
  key
) => (firstItem[key].toLowerCase() > secondItem[key].toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1)
```

However I have a big trouble typing it. `firstItem` and `secondItem` should be generics (T).
`key` should be a valid key of that object so I assume `K extends keyof T` is enough. However inside the function firstItem[key] when I try to use toLowerCase method says:

```
Property 'toLowerCase' does not exist on type 'T[K]'.
```

How do I type that T[K] where K is a single key of that object given as parameter is a string type?

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NB4KgW) meet your needs?  Please test it and get back to me.

Comment: @jcalz Wow, that's pretty simple but the fact that it still suggests "someThirdKey" is a little annoying. Is there any trick to make that disappear as well (other than making a type that filters for only string keys)?

Comment: @vera. "it still suggests 'someThirdKey'" I don't see that, could you demonstrate?  If you care about IntelliSense suggesting keys based on keys of `firstItem` and `secondItem`, though, then I don't understand why you'd want something "other than making a type that filters for only string keys", which is [the way I would do it](https://tsplay.dev/mAd1BN).

Comment: @jcalz do you have any resource where this is explained? `type KeysMatching<T, V> = keyof { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: any }`

Comment: @Konrad https://stackoverflow.com/q/54520676/2887218 has several implementations of the equivalent of `KeysMatching`.  I'm not sure this is in scope for the question as asked, although I guess I'm waiting to hear back from the OP

Comment: @jcalz first solution works flawlessly, HOWEVER our project has some limitations and I cannot use Record, it autoformats Record<K, string> to { [key: K]: string } and says following: An index signature parameter type cannot be a literal type or generic type. Consider using a mapped object type instead.

Comment: ? "autoformats"? That seems out of scope of the question as asked, right? Some strange project build step that turns valid code into invalid code?  You can replace `Record<K, string>` with `{[P in K]: string}` unless that also gets "autoformatted" to something invalid.  I'll write up an answer but I'm not going to worry about `Record<K, string>` because that's a separate issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most straightforward approach is to make `sortArr()` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in the type `K` corresponding to the `key` parameter, and express your `firstItem` and `secondItem` parameter types in terms of it, as `Record<K, string>` [using the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeystype) (or the equivalent `{[P in K]: string}`):

```
const sortArr = <K extends PropertyKey>(
  firstItem: Record<K, string>,
  secondItem: Record<K, string>,
  key: K
) => (firstItem[key].toLowerCase() > secondItem[key].toLowerCase() ? -1 : 1);
```

That compiles with no error since the compiler understands that `firstItem[key]` and `secondItem[key]` are of type `string` (i.e., `Record<K, string>[K]` is assignable to `string`).

Let's make sure it works when you call it:

```
declare const myArray: Array<{
  someKey: string,
  someOtherKey: number,
  someThirdKey: boolean
}>;

myArray.sort((a, b) => sortArr(a, b, 'someKey')); // okay

myArray.sort((a, b) => sortArr(a, b, 'someOtherKey')) // error!
// --------------------------> ~
// Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string'
```

Looks good. The compiler accepts `a` and `b` when you pass in the `"someKey"` key, but rejects them when you pass in `"someOtherKey"`, because the type of `a.someOtherKey` is `number` and not `string`.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?jsx=0&ts=4.9.4#code/MYewdgzgLgBBICcoEEEJgXhgHgNIwFMAPKAsAEwhgAUEQAHApAT1wOYD4AKAWACgYMAGYBLBNACSpALYAuGACUCoBOTwAaOFAQiwAcw7r+giMvDkpBOYrOqNWnfsPGYAa3bzc-AJSYOMLlFxKEtpAG13ZgBdADooEAAZEAB3JgBhAENTLl9-U1AKUIj2WPik1IRM7N8AfhgAWgBGGHlG735+cmUAGwyEAhgC6BhpZlQEDOZ5ccnsAG8XeGkCNimHXT0jATgQZYB5KAALJlX5MABXaQAjJi2TXYIAFUOxclOYK5AQboIMsH4AL4cADcHT4oxmzBi8CQXC4GU0V18GDyiBQaHhiM0AHIlit2NjvO1wWM0JNoWi4QiPsjUUhxpiPji8QdjghVoTfAB6LmENCIACE-B5DXqYvFEslUol-gAfsLeY9mIwYNiLtcmNiYCIqGAQLAshARHowBkrj8YPFLcqBrjtBtsWD+EA)