# How do I guarantee the type of an accessed member in TypeScript with generics?

Tags: typescript, generics, filter

Based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520829/798371), I have some [example code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/CYUwxgNghgTiAEAzArgOzAFwJYHtXwygGsQBnAOWQFsAjEGAClgHMAGALnlWrpgEpONHDgggoqANwBYAFBZUGeoihgEAFQAW85vADes+IfhZgnUhhjbpMo-AAOl1Z261612zgwb6nXfHPIiIiCwqLi8AC+1hGyGACedggA0iBxpACyUBhgWqjMADxqADTwAGoAfPAAvHoA2knG+CRxOIjwagC6ALQA-Jxq9R3wIAAeiqjApGXwPfANziAAbvQRtc2t7R3WYHjmXDgA4iCo9Fhg1UhomLioDAZGy5g4MP25zEX3hqQgopggwABBDAWLA0ZCKchQKggTgpNKZbJvQpvEouXjlD4yPh6T4EYhkSiuRiPDDPWrfX6KQHAyxgiFQkAdPjRWQ7VB7ADuWC8RxOjguKHQ2DwhXKdxsD3ApJe7UxtgpUv+QJBdJAkOhsNSGSyOW0hVRPHoGNk2L8AHozaQcNDsNCphyECd-u14FAplB4MxjqdzqT4GzzDAoPJ4J5vDB7LAGYoYKQSnAMMgYPh4okSiBsgA6XEWgCiMBgz04AJgzGoxwwobaqYQAHIBnDtYi9cUuIaYOUOrX4DmzVgpqhPK7SKQsMxUFAaKICDhI0GbfQqwQEnW0fRa9mJYZCCQKO2GCSyQq-tSVeC1QymdEgA) as follows.  It works fine with no generic as in the cited answer, but fails as soon as I try to make the type a generic instead of Thing:

```
declare function takesNumber(arg0: number): boolean;
interface Thing {
    id: string;
    price: number;
    other: { stuff: boolean };
}
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {[K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never}[keyof T];
const noGeneric = function(
    vector: Thing,
    selectedAttributeName: KeysMatching<Thing, number>,
) {
    takesNumber(vector[selectedAttributeName]);
}
const withGeneric = function<T>(
    vector: T,
    selectedAttributeName: KeysMatching<T, number>,
) { //sometimes we need T as a generic to constrain other parameters, return type, etc.
    //Error: Argument of type 'T[KeysMatching<T, number>]' 
    //is not assignable to parameter of type 'number'.
    takesNumber(vector[selectedAttributeName]);
}
```

Comment: You've run into [ms/TS#30728](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30728); the easiest fix is to reverse your generics like [this](https://tsplay.dev/mbKqoW).  See the answer to the linked duplicate question for more details