# Is it possible to make T[K] extend Type?

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

## Generic Case

In a function

```js
const myFunction = <T, K extends keyof T>(obj: T, key: K): SpecificType => {
  const x: SpecificType = obj[key] // ❌ Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type SpecificType
}
```

Is it possible to define `myFunction(obj, key)` in such a way I can grant that `obj[key] extends SpecificType`?

## Example

Given the following function:

```js
type KeysMatching<T, V> = {
  [K in keyof T]-?: T[K] extends V ? K : never
}[keyof T]

export const groupArrayBy = <
  T extends Record<string, unknown>,
  K extends KeysMatching<T, string | number | symbol>
>(
  array: T[],
  key: K
) => {
  return array.reduce((acc, item) => {
    const group = item[key]
    if (!acc[group]) {
      acc[group] = []
    }
    acc[group].push(item)
    return acc
  }, {} as Record<T[K], T[]>) // ❌ Type 'T[string]' is not assignable to type 'string | number | symbol'
}
```

Typescript complains about defining `{} as Record<T[K], T[]>` because `T[K]` is `unknown` (as given by `T extends Record<string, unknown>`). But, in reality, it is not, `T[K]` should only be `string | number | symbol`, because `K extends KeysMatching<T, string | number | symbol>`

(This auxiliary type was extracted from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54520676/in-typescript-how-to-get-the-keys-of-an-object-type-whose-values-are-of-a-given))

In fact, if I call

```js
const t = [
  {
    valid: 'string',
    alsoValid: 1,
    group: 2,
    invalid: [],
    outroInvalid: {}
  }
]

groupArrayBy(t, 'valid') // ✅ everything ok
groupArrayBy(t, 'invalid') // ❌ not ok, as expected
```

And, even so, typescript cannot tell that, in any valid call to `groupArrayBy([obj], key)`, `obj[key]` will always be `string | number | symbol`, which should be compatible with `Record<T[K], T[]>`

Comment: Without [ms/TS#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992) the compiler can't understand the implication of `KeysMatching` for generics; you'll probably want to add a reverse constraint as shown [in this playground link](https://tsplay.dev/m3B4kN).  Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: This solves the problem! I didn't know TS accepts `T` to be defined as `Type<K>` when K is `OtherType<T>`. Sounds like a dependency loop. Good thing it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript is unable to do much analysis on [conditional types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that depend on [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) type parameters, like `KeysMatching<T, PropertyKey>` inside the body of `groupArrayBy`.  It's more or less opaque to the compiler; it understands that `K extends KeysMatching<T, V>` will be a valid key type for `T`, but it loses the thread that `T[K]` will be assignable to `V`.  It would be nice if there were a "native" `KeysMatching<T, V>` implementation that preserved the intent this way, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992), but for now it's not part of the language, so we'll need to work around it.

The type checker is better at understanding generic [indexed accesses](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into [mapped types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html), so the workaround I'd suggest is to reverse the [constraint](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) and make `T` depend on `K` like `Record<K, PropertyKey>` (using [the `Record<K, V>` utility type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#recordkeys-type) which is a mapped type of the form `{[P in K]: V}`):

```
export const groupArrayBy = <
    T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>,
    K extends keyof T 
>(
    array: T[],
    key: K
) => {
    return array.reduce((acc, item) => {
        const group = item[key]
        if (!acc[group]) {
            acc[group] = []
        }
        acc[group].push(item)
        return acc
    }, {} as Record<T[K], T[]>) // okay
}

interface Foo {
    a: string,
    b: number,
    c: boolean
}
declare const foos: Foo[]
groupArrayBy(foos, "a"); // okay
groupArrayBy(foos, "b"); // okay
groupArrayBy(foos, "c"); // error
// --------> ~~~~
// Argument of type 'Foo[]' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'Record<"c", PropertyKey>[]'.
groupArrayBy(foos, "d"); // error
// --------> ~~~~
// Argument of type 'Foo[]' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'Record<keyof Foo, PropertyKey>[]'.
```

That works without even using `KeysMatching`.  The only downside there might be that the errors are on the `array` when you might expect to see them on the `key`.  If you care, then you can keep the original `KeysMatching` constraint on `K` as well:

```
export const groupArrayBy = <
    T extends Record<K, PropertyKey>,
    K extends KeysMatching<T, PropertyKey>
>(
    array: T[],
    key: K
) => {
    return array.reduce((acc, item) => {
        const group = item[key]
        if (!acc[group]) {
            acc[group] = []
        }
        acc[group].push(item)
        return acc
    }, {} as Record<T[K], T[]>) // okay
}

groupArrayBy(foos, "c"); // error
// --------------> ~~~~
// Argument of type '"c"' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'KeysMatching<Foo, PropertyKey>'.(2345)
groupArrayBy(foos, "d"); // error
// --------------> ~~~~
// Argument of type '"d"' is not assignable to 
// parameter of type 'KeysMatching<Foo, PropertyKey>'.(2345)
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/FAOwhgtgpgzgDmAxlABAJSgNygJxqgb2BRJSgA84B7HAFxUSpBnoHMcqBXOAQRxzABPAEKCUAXhQAeYqTkAVMuVpQQAExjoojHGqkBpADQoAChzi5ag-VEEA+Q7Lkl9Sles0BrW1QBmKeScUOwAKILkwfiEALgCAbQBdR2dSb0FY-SCASgk7FCIUkhwoWk4cEBRIgUEAOmK1TmQQkKREYwBLFQgc8TyCwrlGZjYObgkUTqgIOLSE8ML2-xCAQla49i44BJz+gZS1je4E8cT5lIBfM+cD0a2auE4YAAsQye6ruWLS8srERCvzsYCOdKpoMDo9PI4vokvEEnYskFLkF2iAVDhfEhUAAxKhUfJXMCxFg4VGsZKFABGsRAnAglNwFJSiFilLxABsoGAQEigmptOzIqghiwUL48TBYriqKc5IdeFERIIQuKqDBjAAiMAarIAbhQAHoDSgqJ4hEF5XxqqIVRLNZSdfqjSazYILbcrUIbar1SgNYhHYbjbgODggs6ALRR6NRvIAPwTcfDxr4rDpqnofhQVgsKAA5NLEnmJpoQFR6GAYDB2qxwJTOdn8cmUAgBNB0Sb-DnUHnwTQ9P6NcYzFQLHRrLY7EWau7Np6lba1Zq1IHnSGaM2YzH44nm6n02jO9nBLmC3iiyWUGWK1Wa3WG7Qm3Jna3ICVcEfu-m+7opGks9Kw7mJYE72NOwDAMi4DQPAWIoMI5ZPASQRfjYggwAAsmAtCIE8ZJSPIxgAGp5JIuzONCEwVP+-jyAkEYAPyxFCMJuKoGgoERKAMSgrg0lguBIjMPi0XMQQUNQdAMEwoqWoqojjDIAyKBQ7gcT+ehGKYwHjmhDhXK4qnsZoaGYdhuH4YR2mjiBelBKEhKKsxiRMs4aQZNkuQEgMXxlBUVRCHUUANE0LR-B0XQ9H0HykCKIybOMbzCYIcx7KQiwoCsNybNs3lpdcfzrLcxySLK+WXPlvyIEVOX3I8LxvIilW+T8rQAkCIKVloEIEdCsJQvCTWkMiciouimLICg0p5fsxK0KSIDklc1JXnSDI4K5gyshyXI8nIFWkPyiCCsU0nDGKEpSueqWkHJ1rKj6mranqQYuuacoevJD12n6Dovc6prvbdn33YuvqDv9wb8Buz7Glu8PRjuCZ7jgabQIeWZfnmg7Fu0pblqC1a1mA9aoI+KDNq+7YfpjJ49qZWE4Xhi1SIB1ljlYel5jUIQAEwAMwACwAKxDSQd1et9S5+iukNkNDYawygCMI0jSZK-u6OZl2dP5hqK64-jN5E-eZNPqQL6RG+Ha06eDPmczrCs3iQE2bpk7c3zQuixB5xAA)