# Building a Type from an object with properties of type Boolean?

Tags: typescript, types, type-conversion

I would like to construct a type from this object:

```js
const isSynchronized: Record<SynchronizableField, boolean> = {
    /* synchronized */
    surveyMacroEnvironments: true,
    coordinateReferenceSystemCrs: true,
    transactionType: true,
    epsgTransformation: true,
    startingAgreementDate: true,
    expirationAgreementDate: true,
    transactionTypeNotes: true,
    surveyDataType: true,
    /* not synchronized */
    surveyName: false,
    validationStateCd: false,
    legacy: false,
    notifyOnCreate: false,
    notifyOnValidate: false,
    finalReportLink: false,
    // timestamp fields
    creationDate: false,
    lastUpdate: false,
    // continent and country are handled differently
    continent: false,
    country: false,
};
```

where the type needs to have only the keys with values equal to true, could you please help me or give me any suggestions?

Thanks

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/mAx3ZN) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz yeah that was exactly the approach I was looking for
Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As a first step we have to remove that [type annotation](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-annotations-on-variables) on `isSynchronized`; we need the compiler to *infer* its type and then use that inferred type to compute the key set you're looking for.  You could use [the `satisfies` operator](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-9.html#the-satisfies-operator) instead to make sure the property types are checked against and constrained to `boolean`:

```
const isSynchronized = {
    surveyMacroEnvironments: true,
    coordinateReferenceSystemCrs: true,
    transactionType: true,
    epsgTransformation: true,
    startingAgreementDate: true,
    // ✂ ⋯ ✂
    lastUpdate: false,
    continent: false,
    country: false,
} satisfies Record<string, boolean>;

type IsSynchronized = typeof isSynchronized;
```

Now you can inspect `IsSynchronized` to get the desired type.

---

You're looking for an application of a type function I call `KeysMatching<T, V>`, as requested in [microsoft/TypeScript#48992](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48992) and as discussed in
[In TypeScript, how to get the keys of an object type whose values are of a given type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54520676/2887218).  The idea is that `KeysMatching<T, V>` would evaluate to the [union](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) of property keys of `T` where the property values at those keys are assignable to `V`.  Specifically it looks like you want `KeysMatching<IsSynchronized, true>`.

There's no native `KeysMatching` provided by the language, but there are a number of ways to implement it yourself, with various issues and edge cases.  One approach is a *distributive object type* where we [map over](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) all the properties of `T` and then [index into](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) the result with all the keys to end up with the union of the computed property types.  Like this:

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> =
    { [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends V ? K : never }[keyof T]
```

And let's use it:

```
type SynchronizedKeys = KeysMatching<IsSynchronized, true>;
// type SynchronizedKeys = "surveyMacroEnvironments" | "coordinateReferenceSystemCrs" |
//   "transactionType" | "epsgTransformation" | "startingAgreementDate" | 
//   "expirationAgreementDate" | "transactionTypeNotes" | "surveyDataType"
```

Looks good. If you don't want to keep `KeysMatching` around, you can inline the definition to compute `SynchronizedKeys` directly:

```
type SynchronizedKeys = {
    [K in keyof IsSynchronized]: IsSynchronized[K] extends true ? K : never
}[keyof IsSynchronized];
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAlhAygTzMAFgJ3HAXgUwBMYBeGAbwCgYaYB6AKhglQ2zDyJgbutogCumAG75kAWQCGwbAFEwwuOwC2+MFAgAuGFEwD8AGj41QITIThhJUfACV8AM3yY1wfCmj5lAYUxadeobGAZKQ0lBw4AAqyAAO+Nq6+ka0MPixEADmUZihEA5mytaRYImBKfxQkpgRYJkAgpkuXmpQACLWCQHJwfgAHrFKxeCNzarqHTZlPam6eeElMfEAciA2-klBqYIiYpOSS12bFTSMMGBrzKxYOATEPME7osjLkqraDpIANhBbtMLfOCEYZgRBVGzeQgfb6-E4wL74TLSZDQn5-GgXCIOZAAeTAvnwnVRsOCmLg2LxADVAcCpjBPmi4Q5LN97LEzFAADKWADWxPR9DoOjgqmgb1i9Lg+C+hAgwRkhIi4EmXQZJNSX0k0AAqrFaaqYQK6ELQOpLK0YKFiKABOpMMhLS4YOgrQjiBYHE4XOovsh5eBaq1+XCbXaUfTDUYAL7MYr5KUQGD2UDmAA80EwlkyBhgACMQCAEaEAHwAbkoUDi+BgAEkkNd2JxiGRK-EQA54PW0DcOHdyxWqzAANJiCBSKAYLOpqI5ynF0jBcgwADaQ-gYBgPLE7ZgUQAutooqu92k+jYwLKYJSYAB+YcwbRgfCiTAwKPLrfIHf7ygD+IwRA1zIEdkDHaxJzqVM6xQbtGzuHNNjLShjR0QdANIGAACInjEKQZBAeRFBUVoIEwmAAB8sNMcwWRsewvVcdxQJsHw-DIyjMLmMJgCVMBDnYmBkKFTD0iyHI8gKTAil4gTsKqGos1GfAWgmTpZP6QZcl4pSVPaNSKKwriIAWaIq1WdZ2KErCcOQfZ+N-VtqxgthbiIEDEzIKhUlXddN23DtoIbVzCAPWsuxc3siGPU9z0vTZb3vR9n2cSh30-HdAtg4K93LFDHIAoLIsIdyMOwoRnjwuQFCUcBxg0WTqIsKw6McZxGI8FjfFIiirJoTjcm43j+IMkSMmyAb8kKEFZLFBS6h0uqVXUgYhm0pplMW-TKN6-r5h4xYzLWfBuo4my7KrTCgA)