# Typing a function that converts string dates in JSON objects to Date types

Tags: typescript

We generate typescript interfaces for every API endpoint - one represents the JSON and another represents the "parsed" object. Dates are printed as strings in JSON so we have a global function that takes that raw data, an array listing which fields are dates, and it converts each field into a `Date` so it's easier to use in the javascript.

My problem is that I don't know how to properly type this function so that any "xyzJson" interface (aka `SequenceJson`) can be passed in, and the "parsed" interface is returned (aka `Sequence`)

I assume I'll need generics (something like `<SequenceJson, Sequence>`) but typescript won't let me return the new object based on the old because they don't have "enough in common".

Is there a better approach?

```
// This describes the shape of the raw JSON from this api call
export interface SequenceJson {
  rowId: string
  sequenceId: number
  sequenceTimestamp: string // <-- this is string
}

// This describes the shape our query code returns (Dates have been parsed)
export interface Sequence {
  rowId: string
  sequenceId: number
  sequenceTimestamp: Date // <-- this is now Date
}


// Here's the function for converting the "___Json" object to the one with `Date`s
const parseRecordDates = (record, fields: string[]) => {
  const result = { ...record }

  for (const field of fields) {
    if (field in record) {
      const value = record[field]

      if (value !== null) {
        result[field] = new Date(value)
      }
    }
  }

  return record
}
```

// Example call
`parseRecordDates(json, ['sequenceTimestamp'])`

The function should accept "SequenceJson" and return "Sequence"

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/wR727N) meet your needs? If so I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I need to try it but after looking it over, it looks like what I was after. Our linter requires that we explicitly define return types for functions, which is a bigger part of my issue here than I realized. What would you define as the return type for `parseRecordDates` given what you wrote? I also need to digest that KeysMatching type, that's some fancy ts!

Comment: @helion3 • You could just do [this](https://tsplay.dev/mqxdqN), which is just copying the returned value type to the return type annotation. • I'm interpreting "I need to try it" as "I don't yet know if that approach meets my needs" so I will wait to hear more before I consider writing up a detailed explanation (in case I'm explaining something that doesn't actually work for you).  Please let me know when and how to proceed.

Comment: Yes, this does what I needed. I do need to make a map version of this for arrays of records but this is doing what I needed help with. It's really just a convenience method that uses this core function on an array instead: `const parseRecordsDates = (records, fields) => records.map(record => parseRecordDates(record, fields))`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `parseRecordDates()` to be [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) both in the type `T` of the `record` parameter, and the type `K`  corresponding to just those keys of `T` present in the `fields` parameter.  And we should [constrain](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) `T` or `K` or both so that the property type of `T` at the keys `K` are known to hold `string` properties.

The return type will be `{ [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? Date : T[P] }`.  That's a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) where each key `P` from the keys of `T` will be a key of the return type, and where each property is a [conditional type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/conditional-types.html) that checks if `P` is included in the `fields` element type `K`: if so, then the property will be of the `Date` type, otherwise it is unchanged (and stays `T[P]`, the [indexed access type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) corresponding to the property value of `T` and the index `P`).

Here's one way to write it:

```
const parseRecordDates = <
    T extends Record<K, string>,
    K extends keyof T
>(
    record: T, fields: K[]
): { [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? Date : T[P] } => {
    const result = { ...record } as any
    for (const field of fields) {
        const value = record[field]
        result[field] = new Date(value)
    }       
    return result;
}
```

Here I've constrained `T` so that it is known to have `string` properties at the `K` keys.

I used [the `any` type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#any) to loosen the type checking on `result` and avoid compiler errors.  In general, we can't count on the TypeScript compiler to verify that a function implementation properly returns a generic mapped conditional type.  It will either be too lenient and allow bad implementations, or too strict and complain about correct implementations.  I'm just sidestepping this by using `any`.  There are other approaches, but no matter what, you want to be careful inside the function implementation.

---

That implementation should work as desired:

```
const json: SequenceJson =
    { sequenceId: 123, rowId: "abc", sequenceTimestamp: new Date().toString() };
const seq = parseRecordDates(json, ['sequenceTimestamp']);
/* const seq: {
    rowId: string;
    sequenceId: number;
    sequenceTimestamp: Date;
} */
console.log(seq.sequenceTimestamp.getFullYear()) // 2023
function acceptSequence(x: Sequence) { }
acceptSequence(seq) // okay
```

It also produces an error when you call it incorrectly:

```
parseRecordDates(json, ['sequenceId']); // error
// ------------> ~~~~
// Argument of type 'SequenceJson' is not assignable
// to parameter of type 'Record<"sequenceId", string>'.
```

although the location of the error might be surprising, as it complains about `json` and not `"sequenceId"`.

---

If you care about the location of that error, you can augment the call signature of `parseRecordDates()` to constrain `K` further than just `keyof T`, to just those keys of `T` whose property value types are assignable to `string`.  We can call that `KeysMatching<T, string>`... but for now anyway we need to implement `KeysMatching` ourselves. One implementation of `KeysMatching` is

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> =
    keyof { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: any }
```

(See [In TypeScript, how to get the keys of an object type whose values are of a given type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54520676/2887218) for more information about various implementations).  And then we change the constraint on `K`:

```
const parseRecordDates = <
    T extends Record<K, string>,
    K extends KeysMatching<T, string> // <-- change is here
>(
    record: T, fields: K[]
): { [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? Date : T[P] } => {
    const result = { ...record } as any
    for (const field of fields) {
        const value = record[field]
        result[field] = new Date(value)
    }
    return result;
}
```

And now we see the error in a more expected place.

```
parseRecordDates(json, ['sequenceId']); // error
// -------------------> ~~~~~~~~~~~~
// Type '"sequenceId"' is not assignable to type '"sequenceTimestamp" | "rowId"'.
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgMoQI4FcIiQKQGcB7EZAbwFgAoZO5KYgdwEkATALmULClAHMa9bphx4I7LiCwBbAEbQh9QqNxIAKsBkQecGQAcuPPiH7IA9OeQAeALS3kYABbBCyV914CaAXxo1QSFhEFHRsNRQqWnpGVk5PE0FouhVw8UlkaXlFZJE0jS0dMD1DZAAROEgLKzsHZw8PEGZyyohff2oEUh5kfTgoFQAlCC6oNgrINwBeGyU6dWQIAA9IEDY3YdG2awBpABoEgQA+PbnkHcWV3HXkAGsIAE9iGGR1GiOACjOoEeIxrnUBxgwAgABt1lwdgBtAC6NAAlFxyMgoQAFdxke5PF7qGFcdHLVY3C4AfhaVQBaJhyB8yCmRwoZy6IB6P0IWFBYDpFGQADp+T8tjTkHA3HAQA8zjA-sgPsyesCwWxkM9kIrwYR4YzcsJ5VyAG5wUE4bmCv5sKHqthwnUxHQcsCWkHg6kzEAQJjkiAfQ3GiDws5+XI-MBYKBkNkOgDc7U63S5ACsSCAuGExARk3SzsjUumJPEAIwAJgAzAdYhkAERwOQISsHXMRTTaXQGKQer0feG8sDEVBeUxdmkxuMsrmpbl9AYQTbmiY6D5J0gHKEAckb4mbRRKq5h8JH5gAVMg9Xkkd9mBljAIR8IN0gMlkFFBb8pVJvCq3SvOR7TD+YaHlYhQQgXlQWIfgPlSXl7wgLcv15fgIDAAAxDlQQATQgfouy1SxkCLAAGUsaBgLA8DAYBSBFBAkH0MA0wiD4llTd8kC1ZEg0QOiGLY71UjwqxiFuOBJWoGgpyGX4xnnQhF2TFd1z49hd33apFigRgoBofD7D0-S9IZAA-EyjJ0qwAEEoH4WRcC5VUwAefQUFXRjxCIUhV3cNwmi5UVCGAfgQBrEDzMcYhen6PRkOgFUXkc5zkFXWcxmsStYPYetDlMI5V15DpgpbPokGQAB1YBnB2R5CAAWUqBAXFMbVhASlAqoeWr6sa-hrEBZAADUGSmM5hCxVVkShC5QDuR5VQWUVXkm6lCWuNx+uQMkLnbfVoDxEUJRpDpdXjSLpxS8ZWmmWZbXmS4iQ2aTtn2bL+BOEb6AuFa1jcdrOrABqBF6hsB1es5PneugzX+V4gWdCFzlhM5ER5NEMRm7FXj2gkrm+84Nq9ZBKVRalaXpZrhHoU9I05blkX5XkoeVWkFvFMSKfoaUoFlU8rTitU4c1cn2eOsdkF9E0ZkZp0lRtYWKepx0rVdTIO3nH0jRwAMbsO7WQzDCN7U5V86CDM5JJnR7ZPk5cUSU-J81UqN1OgLSzl0gyPc94zTJ9n23asdQnJc9LlLYSsvMaYg-MIAKgpClBe0cIOkpD+34OKAxK2QAAfZBKwrMO8o6HwgA)

Comment: Do you have advice on how to type a map function for this? For APIs that return multiple records we return an array, so I need to call `parseRecordDates` on multiple `records`. I've tried adapting the signature for an array of records, but because you have lookups, the T needs to represent the base type not the array form, so I'm unsure how to declare that instead.

Comment: Without a [mre] it's hard to say; maybe [this](https://tsplay.dev/wO577m) is what you're looking for. If not, or if you need to discuss further, you might want to open a new question post for it

Comment: Yes that's exactly what I meant. Although your example is almost *exactly what I wrote, but had mis-typed the field name and ran into the problem you described of the error not being in the right place, so it confused me.

`const parseRecordsDates = <T extends object, K extends KeysMatching<T, string>>(
  records: T[],
  fields: K[]
): { [P in keyof T]: P extends K ? Date : T[P] }[] => records.map(record => parseRecordDates<T, K>(record, fields))`