# How to fix typescript dynamic type problem

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, decorator

```
function Middleware<T extends Function>(middleware: Array<{ funcs: Array<keyof T['prototype']>, class: T }>) {

}

class TestValidation {
  Test() { }
}

class FilterValidation {
  Filter() { }
}
```

I am defining Middleware fonkisyon and I want to use giving class functions as string. But not working.

example usage

```
Middleware([
    { funcs: ['Test'], class: TestValidation },
    { funcs: ['Filter'], class: FilterValidation}
  ])
```

this code givin error
`Type '"Filter"' is not assignable to type 'keyof TestValidation'`

how can I fix this problem?

Comment: include `FilterValidation` and `TestValidation`

Comment: obviously the problem is with the type generic parameter, since it is not correctly constrained

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/NBVBkN) meet your needs?  If so then I'll write up an answer explaining; if not, what am I missing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One approach is to make `Middleware` [generic](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html) in a type parameter `T` corresponding to the [tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#tuple-types) of instance types constructed by the `class` property of the `middleware` array.  So if you call `Middleware([{funcs: [], class: Class1}, {funcs: [], class: Class2}])`, where `Class1` and `Class2` are class constructors of types named `Class1` and `Class2` respectively, then `T` would be the type `[Class1, Class2]`.

And we'd make the `middleware` parameter be of a [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-1.html#mapped-types-on-tuples-and-arrays) over `T`, such that each element of `middleware` takes on a type related to the corresponding element of `T`.  For each numeric index `I` from the keys of `T`, the `class` property should be a [construct signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/functions.html#construct-signatures) for `T[I]` (the element of `T` at key `I`), while the `funcs` property should be an array of keys of `T[I]` whose properties are functions.

We can write it like this:

```
function Middleware<T extends readonly object[]>(
  middleware: [...{ [I in keyof T]: {
    funcs: ReadonlyArray<KeysMatching<T[I], Function>>
    class: new () => T[I]
  } }]
) {}
```

where `KeysMatching<T, V>` is a utility type to get the property keys of `T` whose property values are assignable to `V`. One possible definition is

```
type KeysMatching<T, V> = keyof
  { [K in keyof T as T[K] extends V ? K : never]: any }
```

See [In TypeScript, how to get the keys of an object type whose values are of a given type?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54520676/2887218) for more information about how `KeysMatching` works.

Oh, and the `middleware` parameter's type is wrapped in a [variadic tuple type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-4-0.html#variadic-tuple-types) like `[...`+`]` to give the compiler a hint that we want `T` to be inferred as a tuple and not an unordered array.

---

Okay, let's test it:

```
class TestValidation { Test() { } }
class FilterValidation { Filter() { } }

Middleware([
  { funcs: ['Test'], class: TestValidation },
  { funcs: ['Filter'], class: FilterValidation }
]); // okay
```

Looks good.  Let's test it on an example that fails:

```
class Foo {
  a = 1;
  b = 2;
  c() { }
}
Middleware([{
  class: Foo, funcs: ["a", "b", "c"]; // error!
  // ---------------> ~~~  ~~~
}])
```

That fails because `"a"` and `"b"` are keys of `Foo` whose values are not functions.  Only `"c"` is accepted.  So this solution works for both accepting desirable inputs and rejecting undesirable ones.

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcCyBDYBjAFgSwHYHMAeAFQBooA1APigF4oBreAewDMAoKKAbygG0YUPIxasoxKCgTiBAXSgQAHsAi4AJtIpQA-LCgAuKLggA3CACdZhlLhBQAvu3asArrnTBszXFCTY1agA2EADuKOYQJArKqhpQEShq3oF2zABGAFYQHnyyVAAUnFAAtv5BoeEQhnwAdHW8fACSQj5MIGziVjxFXK7uCIYAShCJySAAgubmKCCEcIioGDgEJE2y5ABibh5euFRUPVDogVIDRqFQ+QCUdDTEa0X2DrLsN9zsjuzHp+IQCMAUFCBfxoXbdLjEP7Aa48BwfJzfBDSDbYQIqcyA4FqUHecFQFFoiww3iOT5+ALBMIRfJ8Iq8ProM58ADkkP+zPWRxOSMMbIBQJBnlx9lIdKgDKZzIJ6I55ERZ2lFkxgrBjlkVwR3ORzGYeJQdCgAEYANxFNIGgBMpq46GJcMc5PKVIgNPeNq1hg2OvIEuqACIUH7yH60kGoH70H6XvZ1UA)