# Only allow keys of properties that are type array

Tags: typescript

How do I restrict the `keyof` to only accept `keyof` where the type is of specified type?

```
interface Data {
  items: string[];
  name: string;
}

// so far this accepts any valid key of `T`.
// I want to restrict this so that it only allows keys where the value of the key is type `F`
type Key<T, F = any> = keyof T & string;

interface TextField<T> {
   input: 'text'
   key: Key<T, string>
}

interface ArrayField<T> {
  input: 'text',
  key: Key<T, Array>
}

type Field<T> = TextField<T> | ArrayField<T>;

// Should NOT error
const config: Field<Data>[] = [
   {
      input: 'text'
      key: 'name'
   },
   {
      input: 'array',
      key: 'items'
   }
];

// Should error because the items is not a string and name is not an array
const config: Field<Data>[] = [
   {
      input: 'text'
      key: 'items'
   },
   {
      input: 'array',
      key: 'name'
   }
]
```

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/Nr3ADm) work for you? If yes, I'll write an answer explaining; If not, what am i missing?

Comment: I think so. However one of the error messages is strange it says `Type '"name"' is not assignable to type '"items"'.` Items is a name not a type.

Comment: that's just the error message. `"items"` is also type

Comment: should I proceed with writing the answer?

Comment: I'm probably going to close this as a duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/54520676/2887218) but I'll wait to do so until after an answer appears here if people prefer

Comment: This all works except when the key is for an optional property. Ie if `items` is `{ items? : string[] }`.

Comment: @Ewan check [this one](https://tsplay.dev/Wob2em)

Answer (score 0):

What you are looking for is a mapped type with a combination with key remapping. `key remapping` will allow us to only keep the desired properties:

```
type Key<T, F = any> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends F ? K : never]: T[K];
};
```

Testing:

```
interface Data {
  items?: string[];
  name: string;
}

// "name"
type Case1 = Key<Data, string>
```

To get any array type we will use `readonly unknown[]` as a type because read-only arrays are superset for mutable arrays:

```
// false
type Case1 = readonly number[] extends number[] ? true : false
// true
type Case2 = number[] extends readonly number[] ? true : false
```

Testing:

```
// type Case2 = never
type Case2 = Key<Data, readonly unknown[]>
```

`never`? Interesting, `items` surely match the type, however, the problem is that `items` property is optional. And optional objects are supersets for required ones.

```
// false
type Case1 = { a?: string } extends { a: string } ? true : false;
// true
type Case2 = { a: string } extends { a?: string } ? true : false;
```

To fix it, we will need to use the built-in [NonNullable](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#nonnullabletype) utility type:

```
// string[] | undefined
type Case1 = Data['items']
// string[]
type Case2 = NonNullable<Data['items']>
```

Updating `Key` and other types:

```
type Key<T, F = any> = keyof {
  [K in keyof T as NonNullable<T[K]> extends F ? K : never]: T[K];
};

interface TextField<T> {
  input: 'text';
  key: Key<T, string>;
}

interface ArrayField<T> {
  input: 'array';
  key: Key<T, readonly unknown[]>;
}
```

Final testing:

```
// no error
const config: Field<Data>[] = [
  {
    input: 'text',
    key: 'name',
  },
  {
    input: 'array',
    key: 'items',
  },
];

// error because the items is not a string and name is not an array
const config2: Field<Data>[] = [
  {
    input: 'text',
    key: 'items',
  },
  {
    input: 'array',
    key: 'name',
  },
];
```

[playground](https://tsplay.dev/Wob2em)