using type parameters in generic constraints in TypeScript
I have the following ts code in many places:
(note here's a typescript playground with the example)
let filtered = items.filter(item =>
    item.title.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
    item.name.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()) ||
    item.date.toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
);

So I created this function
function filterByKey<T, K extends keyof T>(items: T[], keys: K[], search: string) {
    return items.filter((item) =>
        keys.some((key) => item[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase()))
    );
}

to call it like this:
let filtered = filterByKey(items, ['title', 'name', 'date'], search));

But I'm getting this error:
Property 'toString' does not exist on type 'T[K]'

I tried like this, but it doesn't seem like a valid syntax
function filterByKey<T, K extends keyof T, T[K] extends string>(items: T[], keys: K[], search: string)

how can I tell ts that the properties of items will support .toString()
or how would you handle such a case so taht typescript won't complain?

I checked this ts documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#using-type-parameters-in-generic-constraints

In your filterByKey function, TypeScript has no idea what type T[K] might be, so it will be treated as unknown, so no method or property of T[K] will be considered valid.
What's missing here is a constraint on the T type, to indicate that any key to T will be of type string
Something like this:
function filterByKey<T extends Record<string, string>, K extends keyof T>(items : T[], keys : K[], search : string) {

This way, T[K] will be of type string, and toLowerCase will be valid (no need to use toString)

thanks a lot, but with T extends Record<string, string> items can ONLY have string properties, I cannot have a number or other data type

In that case instead of typing T you can use a special type for K that allow only keys of T whose values are strings (see this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/54520829/13491714) . However doing this won't be enough to tell typescript that T[K] is of type string, so you'll need a forced assertion to make it knows that item[key] , but that would be ok as you will be sure that item[key] is of type string anyway. Would that be a good solution ?

I tried that but it didn't work any better
type Stringable = { toString: () => string };

type StringProperties<T> = {
  [K in keyof T as T[K] extends Stringable ? K : never]: T[K];
};

function filterByKey<T, K extends keyof StringProperties<T>>(
  items: T[],
  keys: K[],
  search: string
) {
  return items.filter((item) =>
    keys.some((key) =>
      item[key].toString().toLowerCase().includes(search.toLowerCase())
    )
  );
}


I'm publishing this test to give someone a possible idea.
It's always possible to write (item[key] as Stringable) but I don't like it.
If it doesn't solve the problem, this solution offers a good completion.
